# MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector, mariadb-10.5, max-allowed-packet

I'm importing a MySQL dump and getting the following error.

```
$ mysql foo < foo.sql 
ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 96: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

Apparently there are attachments in the database, which makes for very large inserts.

---

This is on my local machine, a Mac with MySQL 5 installed from the MySQL package.

Where do I change `max_allowed_packet` to be able to import the dump?

Is there anything else I should set?

Just running `mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M …` resulted in the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change max\_allowed\_packet size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

Comment: @Muleskinner, this question was posted 3 years before the one you mention and I'm pointing this out 4 years after your comment. :p

Comment: Webyog.com Link is broken: 404

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49465122/6381711), a similar error, "Packet for query is to large (5526600 > 1048576).", was caused by a wrong password entry, when connecting to MySQL database using DataGrip 2016.1 by JetBrains, and got resolved when rectified (using the right password corresponding to the MySQL database user).

Answer (score 759, accepted):

You probably have to change it for both the client (you are running to do the import) AND the daemon mysqld that is running and accepting the import.

For the client, you can specify it on the command line:

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=100M -u root -p database < dump.sql
```

Also, **change the my.cnf or my.ini file** (usually found in /etc/mysql/) under the mysqld section and set:

```
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

or you could run these **commands** in a MySQL console connected to that same server:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

(Use a very large value for the packet size.)

Comment: I have a server with 16 GB of RAM, is it a bad idea to set `max_allowed_packet` to 100 MB?

Comment: as an aside, to run those set commands your mysql user must have SUPER privileges or it will fail with `ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation`

Comment: FYI - it helped me to solve a DIFFERENT error - "#2006 server has gone away"

Comment: I also got the "ERROR 2006: MySQL server has gone away". This was on a windows machine. On a Linux machine I got the "ERROR 1153: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes" for the same dump file. Mysql versions are also different on the machines so I'm not really sure if it is related to the version or OS.

Comment: Be aware that using "set global" works until the next mysql service restart.

Comment: This did the trick for me except that 100MB caused issues with InnoDB. I changed it to 10MB and it worked fine.

Comment: Skip "set global" and the final ";" when adding these values to the my.ini or my.cnf files. Ex: "net_buffer_length=1000000" in my.conf.

Comment: On CentOS 5, my.cnf is located at /etc/my.cnf

Comment: For those using PHPMyAdmin I was able to do this technique by starting on the home page of PHPMyAdmin, then clicking the variables tab, then you can search for 'packet' or 'buffer' to narrow down and edit from there.

Comment: I've had the same problem and I spent many hours for it because I restore DB using MySQL Workbench which does not show error about packet size. When I use SQLYog, it shows something like package size is not enough. Changing that value to 500MB solves the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem and in my case changing my.ini file on server was enough. Did not need to add --max_allowed_packets to the client call

Comment: @Rustavore On CentOS 7, inside the `my.cnf` that `max_allowed_packet` does not exist. I added it, saved the file, restarted mariadb and it didn't work. The problem actually was a wordpress plugin that produced that backup.sql file. Instead it was solved by making the backup through phpmyadmin

Comment: The command-line option DID NOT work for me (MySQL 5.7 on windows), but setting the option in `my.ini` DID WORK. (So try changing it there, before you start hunting for other sources of the error)

Comment: setting max_allowed_packet=100M in my.cnf was enough for me.

Comment: conf file locations for MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#option-file-locations-on-linux-unix-mac

Comment: On Windows and using WAMP left click wamp icon and select mysql. then settings and change it there. It will auto restart everything

Comment: I had to add the lines to /etc/my.cnf file under `[mysqld]` section (CentOS 7, MariaDB 5.5) to make it work.

Comment: +1 @Michael  Users of this answer must not forget `[mysqld]` otherwise you will get `error: Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line:`... Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43451106/227926

Answer (score 143):

As michaelpryor said, you have to change it for *both* the client *and* the daemon mysqld  server.

His solution for the client command-line is good, but the ini files don't always do the trick, depending on configuration.

So, open a terminal, type mysql to get a mysql prompt, and issue these commands:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

Keep the mysql prompt open, and run your command-line SQL execution on a second terminal..

Comment: Solved the problem for me; the import I'm doing is a once-off, and I can't easily change the configuration. This worked great. :D

Answer (score 50):

This can be changed in your `my.ini` file (on Windows, located in \Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server) under the server section, for example:

```
[mysqld]

max_allowed_packet = 10M
```

Comment: on a mac, file obviously located elsewhere.

Comment: sure, but the configuration is still somewhere although I don't know the exact location

Comment: For me in Fedora 20 with MariaDB, placing that setting at the end of  /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf did the trick. I had to restart the service of course... sudo nano systemctl restart mariadb.service

Comment: The file would more likely be "my.cnf" and on nix systems, typically in /etc/ or /usr/local/etc. Once you edit, be sure to restart mysql server to apply change.

Answer (score 20):

The fix is to increase the MySQL daemon’s max_allowed_packet. You can do this to a running daemon by logging in as Super and running the following commands.

```
# mysql -u admin -p

mysql> set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then to import your dump:

```
gunzip < dump.sql.gz | mysql -u admin -p database
```

Comment: What version of MySQL were you running this on?

Comment: This one works for my server. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

#### Re my.cnf on Mac OS X when using MySQL from the mysql.com dmg package distribution

By default, my.cnf is nowhere to be found.

You need to copy one of `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/my*.cnf` to `/etc/my.cnf` and restart `mysqld`. (Which you can do in the MySQL preference pane if you installed it.)

Comment: The default config in place for OSX appears to be my-medium.cnf, although the max_allowed_packet size is the same in my-large.cnf ... until you start changing things :)

Comment: In my case /usrl/local/mysql/my.cnf not worked until I copy it to /etc/my.cnf.

Answer (score 17):

In etc/my.cnf try changing the max_allowed _packet and net_buffer_length to

```
max_allowed_packet=100000000
net_buffer_length=1000000
```

if this is not working then try changing to

```
max_allowed_packet=100M
net_buffer_length=100K
```

Answer (score 8):

On CENTOS 6 /etc/my.cnf , under [mysqld] section the correct syntax is:

```
[mysqld]
# added to avoid err "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes"
#
net_buffer_length=1000000 
max_allowed_packet=1000000000
#
```

Answer (score 8):

I have resolved my issue by this query

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

and check max_allowed_packet with this query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a `max_allowed_packet` variable issuing a command like

`mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M
 -u root -p database < dump.sql`

Comment: tried that, didn't work. whole dump in 272mb, tried with max higher than that.

Answer (score 5):

Slightly unrelated to your problem, so here's one for Google.

If you didn't mysqldump the SQL, it might be that your SQL is broken.

I just got this error by accidentally having an unclosed string literal in my code. Sloppy fingers happen.

That's a fantastic error message to get for a runaway string, thanks for that MySQL!

Comment: I also got this error because of broken SQL. More specifically, my table has null constraints and my code was INSERTing null values. Instead of giving me an informative error, MySQL returned the `max_allowed_packet` error. If it helps for those in the future, I was INSERTing using the pandas API `df.to_sql(...)`

Comment: Something similar happened to me (and I did use `mysqldump`. Fortunately my IDE highlighting caught it once I knew to look for the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Error:**

> ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 6772: Got a packet bigger than
>   'max_allowed_packet' bytes Operation failed with exitcode 1

**QUERY:**

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

**Max value:**

```
Default Value (MySQL >= 8.0.3)  67108864
Default Value (MySQL <= 8.0.2)  4194304
Minimum Value   1024
Maximum Value   1073741824
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes type setting:

```
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

in my.ini is not working.

Try to determine the my.ini as follows:

```
set-variable = max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

or

```
set-variable = max_allowed_packet = 1000000000
```

Then restart the server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Answer (score 2):

It is  a security risk to have `max_allowed_packet` at higher value, as an attacker can push bigger sized packets and crash the system.

So, Optimum Value of `max_allowed_packet` to be tuned and tested.

It is to better to change when required *(using `set global max_allowed_packet = xxx`)* 
than to have it as part of *my.ini* or *my.conf*.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in a shared hosting environment and I have hosted a website based on Drupal. I cannot edit the `my.ini` file or `my.conf` file too.

So, I deleted all the tables which were related to `Cache` and hence I could resolve this issue. Still I am looking for a perfect solution / way to handle this problem.

**Edit** - Deleting the tables created problems for me, coz Drupal was expecting that these tables should be existing. So I emptied the contents of these tables which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set max_allowed_packet to the same (or more) than what it was when you dumped it with mysqldump. If you can't do that, make the dump again with a smaller value.

That is, assuming you dumped it with mysqldump. If you used some other tool, you're on your own.