# Multiple INSERT statements vs. single INSERT with multiple VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm running a performance comparison between using 1000 INSERT statements:

```
INSERT INTO T_TESTS (TestId, FirstName, LastName, Age) 
   VALUES ('6f3f7257-a3d8-4a78-b2e1-c9b767cfe1c1', 'First 0', 'Last 0', 0)
INSERT INTO T_TESTS (TestId, FirstName, LastName, Age) 
   VALUES ('32023304-2e55-4768-8e52-1ba589b82c8b', 'First 1', 'Last 1', 1)
...
INSERT INTO T_TESTS (TestId, FirstName, LastName, Age) 
   VALUES ('f34d95a7-90b1-4558-be10-6ceacd53e4c4', 'First 999', 'Last 999', 999)
```

..versus using single INSERT statement with 1000 values:

```
INSERT INTO T_TESTS (TestId, FirstName, LastName, Age) 
VALUES 
('db72b358-e9b5-4101-8d11-7d7ea3a0ae7d', 'First 0', 'Last 0', 0),
('6a4874ab-b6a3-4aa4-8ed4-a167ab21dd3d', 'First 1', 'Last 1', 1),
...
('9d7f2a58-7e57-4ed4-ba54-5e9e335fb56c', 'First 999', 'Last 999', 999)
```

To my big surprise, the results are the opposite of what I thought:

- 1000 INSERT statements: **290 msec.**
- 1 INSERT statement with 1000 VALUES: **2800 msec.**

The test is executed directly in MSSQL Management Studio with SQL Server Profiler used for measurement (and I've got similar results running it from C# code using SqlClient, which is even more suprising considering all the DAL layers roundtrips)

Can this be reasonable or somehow explained? How come, a supposedly faster method results in 10 times (!) **worse** performance?

Thank you.

EDIT: Attaching execution plans for both:
[image: Exec Plans]

Comment: these are clean tests, nothing is executing in parallel, no repeated data (each query is with different data, of course, to avoid simple caching)

Comment: are there any triggers involved?

Comment: I converted a program to TVP to get past the 1000 limit on values and got a big performance gain.  I will run a comparison.

Comment: relevant: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/comparing-multiple-rows-insert-vs-single-row-insert-with-three-data-load-methods/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

> **Addition:** SQL Server 2012 shows some improved performance in this area but doesn't seem to tackle the specific issues noted below. This
>   should [apparently be fixed](https://web.archive.org/web/20130826000239/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/717664/insert-performance-with-non-parameterised-table-valued-constructors-degrades-non-linearly-with-number-of-clauses) in the next major version **after**
>   SQL Server 2012!

Your plan shows the single inserts are using parameterised procedures (possibly auto parameterised) so parse/compile time for these should be minimal.

I thought I'd look into this a bit more though so set up a loop ([script](https://gist.github.com/1522552)) and tried adjusting the number of `VALUES` clauses and recording the compile time.

I then divided the compile time by the number of rows to get the average compile time per clause. The results are below

[image: Graph]

Up until 250 `VALUES` clauses present the compile time / number of clauses has a slight upward trend but nothing too dramatic.

[image: Graph]

But then there is a sudden change.

That section of the data is shown below.

```
+------+----------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| Rows | CachedPlanSize | CompileTime | CompileMemory | Duration/Rows |
+------+----------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|  245 |            528 |          41 |          2400 | 0.167346939   |
|  246 |            528 |          40 |          2416 | 0.162601626   |
|  247 |            528 |          38 |          2416 | 0.153846154   |
|  248 |            528 |          39 |          2432 | 0.157258065   |
|  249 |            528 |          39 |          2432 | 0.156626506   |
|  250 |            528 |          40 |          2448 | 0.16          |
|  251 |            400 |         273 |          3488 | 1.087649402   |
|  252 |            400 |         274 |          3496 | 1.087301587   |
|  253 |            400 |         282 |          3520 | 1.114624506   |
|  254 |            408 |         279 |          3544 | 1.098425197   |
|  255 |            408 |         290 |          3552 | 1.137254902   |
+------+----------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The cached plan size which had been growing linearly suddenly drops but CompileTime increases 7 fold and CompileMemory shoots up. This is the cut off point between the plan being an auto parametrized one (with 1,000 parameters) to a non parametrized one. Thereafter it seems to get linearly less efficient (in terms of number of value clauses processed in a given time).

Not sure why this should be. Presumably when it is compiling a plan for specific literal values it must perform some activity that does not scale linearly (such as sorting).

It doesn't seem to affect the size of the cached query plan when I tried a query consisting entirely of duplicate rows and neither affects the order of the output of the table of the constants (and as you are inserting into a heap time spent sorting would be pointless anyway even if it did).

Moreover if a clustered index is added to the table the plan still shows an explicit sort step so it doesn't seem to be sorting at compile time to avoid a sort at run time.

[image: Plan]

I tried to look at this in a debugger but the public symbols for my version of SQL Server 2008 don't seem to be available so instead I had to look at the equivalent `UNION ALL` construction in SQL Server 2005.

A typical stack trace is below

```
sqlservr.exe!FastDBCSToUnicode()  + 0xac bytes  
sqlservr.exe!nls_sqlhilo()  + 0x35 bytes    
sqlservr.exe!CXVariant::CmpCompareStr()  + 0x2b bytes   
sqlservr.exe!CXVariantPerformCompare<167,167>::Compare()  + 0x18 bytes  
sqlservr.exe!CXVariant::CmpCompare()  + 0x11f67d bytes  
sqlservr.exe!CConstraintItvl::PcnstrItvlUnion()  + 0xe2 bytes   
sqlservr.exe!CConstraintProp::PcnstrUnion()  + 0x35e bytes  
sqlservr.exe!CLogOp_BaseSetOp::PcnstrDerive()  + 0x11a bytes    
sqlservr.exe!CLogOpArg::PcnstrDeriveHandler()  + 0x18f bytes    
sqlservr.exe!CLogOpArg::DeriveGroupProperties()  + 0xa9 bytes   
sqlservr.exe!COpArg::DeriveNormalizedGroupProperties()  + 0x40 bytes    
sqlservr.exe!COptExpr::DeriveGroupProperties()  + 0x18a bytes   
sqlservr.exe!COptExpr::DeriveGroupProperties()  + 0x146 bytes   
sqlservr.exe!COptExpr::DeriveGroupProperties()  + 0x146 bytes   
sqlservr.exe!COptExpr::DeriveGroupProperties()  + 0x146 bytes   
sqlservr.exe!CQuery::PqoBuild()  + 0x3cb bytes  
sqlservr.exe!CStmtQuery::InitQuery()  + 0x167 bytes 
sqlservr.exe!CStmtDML::InitNormal()  + 0xf0 bytes   
sqlservr.exe!CStmtDML::Init()  + 0x1b bytes 
sqlservr.exe!CCompPlan::FCompileStep()  + 0x176 bytes   
sqlservr.exe!CSQLSource::FCompile()  + 0x741 bytes  
sqlservr.exe!CSQLSource::FCompWrapper()  + 0x922be bytes    
sqlservr.exe!CSQLSource::Transform()  + 0x120431 bytes  
sqlservr.exe!CSQLSource::Compile()  + 0x2ff bytes
```

So going off the names in the stack trace it appears to spend a lot of time comparing  strings.

[This KB article](http://kbalertz.com/281769/Exception-Access-Violation-Encountered-During-Query-Normalization.aspx) indicates that `DeriveNormalizedGroupProperties` is associated with what used to be called the [normalization](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/inside-sql-server-parse-compile-and-optimize) stage of query processing

This stage is now called binding or algebrizing and it takes the expression parse tree output from the previous parse stage and outputs an algebrized expression tree (query processor tree) to go forward to optimization (trivial plan optimization in this case) [[ref]](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/the-sql-server-query-optimizer/).

I tried one more experiment ([Script](https://gist.github.com/1580007)) which was to re-run the original test but looking at three different cases.

1. First Name and Last Name Strings of length 10 characters with no duplicates.
2. First Name and Last Name Strings of length 50 characters with no duplicates.
3. First Name and Last Name Strings of length 10 characters with all duplicates.

[image: Graph]

It can clearly be seen that the longer the strings the worse things get and that conversely the more duplicates the better things get. As previously mentioned duplicates don't affect the cached plan size so I presume that there must be a process of duplicate identification when constructing the algebrized expression tree itself.

**Edit**

One place where this information is leveraged is [shown by @Lieven here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11475343/73226)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('Lieven1', 1),
             ('Lieven2', 2),
             ('Lieven3', 3))Test (name, ID)
ORDER BY name, 1/ (ID - ID)
```

Because at compile time it can determine that the `Name` column has no duplicates it skips ordering by the secondary `1/ (ID - ID)` expression at run time (the sort in the plan only has one `ORDER BY` column) and no divide by zero error is raised. If duplicates are added to the table then the sort operator shows two order by columns and the expected error is raised.

Comment: The magic number you have is NumberOfRows / ColumnCount = 250. Change your query to only use three columns and the change will happen at 333. The magic number 1000 could be something like the max number of parameters used in a cached plan. It seams to be "easier" to generate a plan with a `<ParameterList>` than one with a `<ConstantScan><Values><Row>` list.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Agreed. The 250 row one with 1000 values gets auto parameterised the 251 row doesn't so that does seem to be the difference. Not sure why though. Perhaps it spends time sorting the literal values looking for duplicates or something when it has these.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson  Do you mean the magic number is NumberOfRows * ColumnCount = 1000 ?

Comment: @Blam  - Yes. When the total number of elements is more than 1000 (NumberOfRows * ColumnCount) the query plan changed to use `<ConstantScan><Values><Row>` instead of `<ParameterList>`.

Answer (score 26):

It is not too surprising: the execution plan for the tiny insert is computed once, and then reused 1000 times. Parsing and preparing the plan is quick, because it has only four values to del with. A 1000-row plan, on the other hand, needs to deal with 4000 values (or 4000 parameters if you parameterized your C# tests). This could easily eat up the time savings you gain by eliminating 999 roundtrips to SQL Server, especially if your network is not overly slow.

Answer (score 10):

The issue probably has to do with the time it takes to compile the query.

If you want to speed up the inserts, what you really need to do is wrap them in a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO T_TESTS (TestId, FirstName, LastName, Age) 
   VALUES ('6f3f7257-a3d8-4a78-b2e1-c9b767cfe1c1', 'First 0', 'Last 0', 0);
INSERT INTO T_TESTS (TestId, FirstName, LastName, Age) 
   VALUES ('32023304-2e55-4768-8e52-1ba589b82c8b', 'First 1', 'Last 1', 1);
...
INSERT INTO T_TESTS (TestId, FirstName, LastName, Age) 
   VALUES ('f34d95a7-90b1-4558-be10-6ceacd53e4c4', 'First 999', 'Last 999', 999);
COMMIT TRAN;
```

From C#, you might also consider using a table valued parameter. Issuing multiple commands in a single batch, by separating them with semicolons, is another approach that will also help.

Comment: Re: "Issuing multiple commands in a single batch": that helps a little, but not a lot. But I definitely agree with the other two options of either wrapping in a TRANSACTION (does TRANS actually work or should it just be TRAN?) or using a TVP.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation trying to convert a table with several 100k rows with a C++ program (MFC/ODBC).

Since this operation took a very long time, I figured bundling multiple inserts into one (up to 1000 due to [MSSQL limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)). My guess that a lot of single insert statements would create an overhead similar to what is described [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/8/17/mssql_and_large_insert_statements).

However, it turns out that the conversion took actually quite a bit longer:

```
        Method 1       Method 2     Method 3 
        Single Insert  Multi Insert Joined Inserts
Rows    1000           1000         1000
Insert  390 ms         765 ms       270 ms
per Row 0.390 ms       0.765 ms     0.27 ms
```

So, 1000 single calls to CDatabase::ExecuteSql each with a single INSERT statement (method 1) are roughly twice as fast as a single call to CDatabase::ExecuteSql with a multi-line INSERT statement with 1000 value tuples (method 2).

Update: So, the next thing I tried was to bundle 1000 separate INSERT statements into a single string and have the server execute that (method 3). It turns out this is even a bit faster than method 1.

Edit: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition (64-bit) v10.0.2531.0