# Is this way is optimized to retrieve values which are not exist in database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

To retrieve values which are not in db, I use Common Table Expression like this :

```
;WITH new_id (id) AS (
  SELECT '0x01'
  UNION ALL SELECT '0x00'
  UNION ALL SELECT '0x03'
  UNION ALL SELECT '0x04'
  UNION ALL SELECT '0x05'
)

SELECT  id AS p
FROM   new_id ni EXCEPT(SELECT id FROM table)
```

Is this an optimized way to retrieve values which are not stored in DB ?

Kind regards,

Florian

Comment: Why not use an in memory table (@table_vaiable) instead of a CTE?

Comment: How many rows do you tend to have in the CTE? @Kane `@table_variables` are not in memory tables (or they might be but no more than `#temp` tables are)

Comment: @Martin Smith : 30 rows maximum I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be fine.

For a large number of rows (especially if they contain long string values) I have noticed that these internal tables of constants can [take a long time to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values/8640583#8640583) but I doubt you will hit this issue for 30 rows.

From a quick test this end they have an advantage over table variables as SQL Server seems to maintain some statistical information about them so can choose an appropriate join type.

I just tried a CTE with 500 rows and 50 distinct values and the estimated number of rows in the plan below was correct. (though it is a bit of a shame that having worked all this stuff out at compile time and presumably having generated a distinct list of `id`s for that purpose that SQL Server doesn't just substitute that into the plan instead of having to do it again at run time)

[image: Plan]