# optimize insert query on sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I recently built an app to test the speed difference between writing 100000 lines to a text file and 100000 inserts into a database

Here is the heart of the code

```
    private void RunTestBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch FFtimer = new Stopwatch();
        FFtimer.Start();
        RunFFTest();
        FFtimer.Stop();
        TimeSpan FFts = FFtimer.Elapsed;
        string FFelapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        FFts.Hours, FFts.Minutes, FFts.Seconds,
        FFts.Milliseconds / 10);
        FFLabel.Content = "Flat File: " + FFelapsedTime;

        Stopwatch Datatimer = new Stopwatch();
        Datatimer.Start();
        DataFFTest();
        Datatimer.Stop();
        TimeSpan Datats = Datatimer.Elapsed;
        string DataelapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        Datats.Hours, Datats.Minutes, Datats.Seconds,
        Datats.Milliseconds / 10);
        DBLabel.Content = "Database: " + DataelapsedTime;

    }
    void RunFFTest()
    {
        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"F:\test\FFtest.txt"))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i< 100000; i++)
            {
            writer.WriteLine("test");
            }

        }
    }

    void DataFFTest()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=EMMY;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=SqlServiceUser;Password=MyPassword;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Test')";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The end result is that the Flat file writing took 1 millisecond and the sql inserts took nine minutes and forty one seconds.  I know the database will take longer, but is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible options ...

1. Use transactions (do multiple inserts per transaction)
2. Use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) API

Comment: So in the future we are planning to do inserts on different things, so I just want a way to speed up inserts or the database in general (if thats possible)

Comment: If by "different things", you mean multiple tables, the same advice still applies.  A single transaction may include DML statements for multiple tables.  In the case of `SqlBulkCopy`, you'd have to execute a separate statement per table.  So, for example, if you have 5 tables, you would execute 5 SqlBulkCopy operations.  In both cases, the underlying idea is to insert in batches so that you minimize the overhead of the locking and the transaction log.

Comment: Oops sorry, should be more clear.  I meant to say it would not be inserting "test" over and over, it would be inserting a variety of strings and integers, which seems like it would not work for the sqlbulkcopy

Comment: You can still use `SqlBulkCopy`.  The easiest way is probably to create a `DataTable` containing the rows you want to insert, then call `SqlBulkCopy` with the `DataTable` as the source.  Here's an example: http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/c-bulk-copying-data-into-ms-sql-server-with-datatables/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do it as one single insert statement, rather than many.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Test'), ('Test'), ('Test') ....";
```

Comment: There is a maximum of 1,000 rows that can be inserted in this way and [it might actually be slower.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8635818/73226)

Comment: That article takes no account of CreateCommand or ExecuteNonQuery as is being done within the loop here.  I think it would be worth a try as it would not take at all long to test under the conditions in question.

Comment: The OP there says " I've got similar results running it from C# code using SqlClient, which is even more suprising considering all the DAL layers roundtrips" for short strings like `test` with lots of duplicates things may be better though!