# inserting different data with different id on single save button

Tags: php, mysql

I do have three fields which are text input which is of type number.these three data are being saved with different ids but on the same save button.i.e i am inserting data into all the field and then clicking on the save button but the my first data is being saved by different id and the same for the rest of two data.for example if i put 1 in first input,2 in second and 3 in the next since these are number type.but 1 is being saved by say by id:11,2 is being saved by say by id:12,3 is being saved by say by id:13.
my view is like below:

```
<form class="form">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">High Priority</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="number"name="sval"id="sval"/>Days
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label ">Low Priority</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="number"name="sval" id="sval"/>Days</div>
        </div>
         <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label ">Normal</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="number" name="sval" id="sval"/>Days </div>
        </div>
        <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary insert">Save</button>
</form>
```

and the queries are:

```
var sqld:String;
 sqld = "Delete from app_settings where kunnr = '"+kunnr+"' and ( skey = 'hp_days' or skey = 'np_days' or skey = 'lp_days' )";
 wcisql.query(sqld,'clearRDays');
}
public function saveRDays():void{
 var sqlu:String;
 sqlu = "Insert into app_settings(kunnr,skey,sval) Values ('"+kunnr+"','hp_days','"+hp_days.value+"')";
 wcisql.query(sqlu,'saveRDays');
 sqlu = "Insert into app_settings(kunnr,skey,sval) Values ('"+kunnr+"','np_days','"+np_days.value+"')";
 wcisql.query(sqlu,'saveRDays');
 sqlu = "Insert into app_settings(kunnr,skey,sval) Values ('"+kunnr+"','lp_days','"+lp_days.value+"')";
 wcisql.query(sqlu,'saveRDays');
 $sql = "Select * from app_settings where kunnr = '$kunnr'";
   }
```

i am adding image as well so that u can get better idea:
[image] 
how to do this please suggest..

and for my view:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Multiple Insert statement

ckeck out this referenced link:

[Multiple INSERT statements vs. single INSERT with multiple VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values)
&
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can only use one ID for each HTML element. 
So there are two ways to achieve this, one is dynamic the second is static.

Static Solutions:

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">High Priority</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="number"name="sval1"id="sval1"/>Days
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label ">Low Priority</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="number"name="sval2" id="sval2"/>Days</div>
    </div>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label ">Normal</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" name="sval3" id="sval3"/>Days </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary insert">Save</button>
```

Dynamic Solution

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">High Priority</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" name="sval[]"/>Days
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label ">Low Priority</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" name="sval[]"/>Days</div>
    </div>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label ">Normal</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" name="sval[]"/>Days </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary insert">Save</button>
```

Now when you post the form the items will come in array so you have an array
$_GET['sval'] or $_POST['sval'] contains array(1,2,3)

Comment: how my query look like and i want to do this by ajax..so please give me full code..