# SQL Server inserts slow down over time

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

Not sure if this is a question for here or the DBA forum, but here is some background to my problem. I have an application written in C# which uses the Gentle Framework to interface with our database. The issue I am running into has shown up on two different servers, both running SQL Server 2008 R2. One server is running Windows Server 2003 with 16GB of RAM, and the other is running Windows Server 2008 R2 with 64GB of RAM. Also we are running gigabit intranet so I doubt it is either a resource or network issue.

That being said my issue is... when inserting into the database, each insert is taking a little more time starting with about 30ms and building up to about 1900ms before suddenly taking 189549ms (a little over 3 minutes). After that 3 minute insert, the time drops down to about 10ms and starts building up again. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng74hrlno7ke52r/TimeTable.txt?m) is a link to my log file showing the time in ms and the query. Unfortunately, due to what has been called "proprietary", I can't share the exact inserts with you but I can answer general questions about the details.

Some additional details:

- The log file linked only shows queries which took over 10ms, there are many more queries in the log between the inserts, however they are only taking 1-2ms. I can link one with all of the queries.
- I have looked at other questions regarding a similar issues but they have either been about RAID or multiple inserts vs multiple values statements
- These are parameterized queries
- The tables are indexed and it is not possible to remove these because other applications are using these tables and depend on those indexes.
- I don't think I have much choice in changing how records are inserted because Gentle is generating the SQL.
- I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values) which I think is close.
- I believe that Gentle is doing all of this in 1 transaction, and I have been told that "it should be done in 1 transaction, and we are not going to break it apart"

Comment: I suggest you use SQL Profiler to monitor the SQL that is being generated. I've rarely seen a framework generate sensible SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, without you providing more details, this is probably going to be nearly impossible to answer. You're basically asking how you can generally make inserts faster - there are entire books on that subject. Most likely, there's an architectural problem that needs addressed (perhaps a trigger on the table?).