# foreach with do while for building insert query

Tags: sql, powershell

I have this PowerShell script

```
 $CSV = Import-Csv "records.csv"
        Foreach ($Row in $CSV) {
            $Q = "INSERT INTO database..table([id], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES ('"+ ($Row.'id') + "','" + ($Row.'First Name') + "','" + ($Row.'Last Name') + "')"
            Invoke-QsSqlQuery -query $Q -SQLServer <servername> -database <databaseName>
            }
```

**Note**: `Invoke-QsSqlQuery` is my own function.

My problem  is that I am invoking a SQL command for every row. This has created a performance issue.

I want to build `$Q` so that it will have 1000 rows and then invoke it into SQL server. A bulk is not possible because, with bulk, the file needs to be copied locally on the server and that is not allowed.

With a `do while` I can count to 1000 that's not to hard but what if my remaining record are less than 1000?

How can I build a query that will update multiple records at once?

Comment: This can be done from what I have seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/how-do-i-insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-dbo-blah-part). What version of sql server are you using. You might have a record limit that needs to be accounted for

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly simple

1. Assign all the statements to a string array (your foreach loop is totally appropriate here)
2. Split the string array into multiple string arrays of 1000 or less
3. Concatenate each group
4. Execute query

---

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "records.csv"

$SQLServer   = "dbserver.corp.company.tld"
$SQLDatabase = "database"

# Set up a string format template
$InsertTemplate = "INSERT INTO database..table([id], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}')"

# Generate all insert statements and store in string array
$AllInserts = foreach($Row in $CSV){
    $InsertTemplate -f $Row.id,$Row.'First Name',$Row.'Last Name'
}

# Split array into an array of 1000 (or fewer) string arrays
$RowArrays = for($i=0; $i -lt $AllInserts.Length; $i+=1000){
    ,@($AllInserts[$i..($i+999)])
}

# Foreach array of 1000 (or less) insert statements, concatenate them with a new line and invoke it
foreach($RowArray in $RowArrays){
    $Query = $RowArray -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
    Invoke-QsSqlQuery -query $Query -SQLServer $SQLServer -database $SQLDatabase
}
```

Comment: I _was_ working on building a statement with one INSERT statement. Since I don't know I am curious: Would the single insert be faster that multiples you have? Or is it 6 of one and half a dozen of the other?

Comment: @Matt Thought about that as well, but then I glanced [over this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values) - seems that it might cause a huge increase in compile time

Comment: Still, should be trivial to do the other way around, just remove the "INSERT INTO" part from the template and prepend it to the final query string before execution

Comment: Iam getting an error.Cannot convert value "INSERT INTO <values>" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct fo
rmat."
At line:2 char:16
+             ,@($AllInserts[$i]..$AllInserts[$i+999])
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger'

Comment: Change $AllInserts.Length to $AllInserts.Count

Comment: And enclose $AllInserts[] in parentheses

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean by "And enclose $AllInserts[] in parentheses"

Comment: $AllInserts[$i+999] becomes ($AllInserts[$i+999])

Comment: Sill getting error this is my code now:
'        # Split array into an array of 1000 (or fewer) string arrays
        $RowArrays = for($i=0; $i -lt $AllInserts.Count; $i+=1000){
            ,@($AllInserts[$i]..($AllInserts[$i+999]))
           # write-host $AllInserts
        }'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84209/discussion-between-h-schutte-and-mathias-r-jessen).

Answer (score 1):

depending on some factors you may be able to use [bulk insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) instead of multiple insert.

the requirements to satisfy are 2:
- the file to import must be on the sql server
- CSV files must comply with specific requirements stated on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188609.aspx) for the format of the file to be imported

should you be able to comply with the above requirements you may be able to import the whole file with a statement simple as this one:

```
BULK INSERT database..table
FROM 'C:\FileToImport.csv';
GO
```

Comment: this is the quickes way but i can not copy the file to the sql server. like i said. but thx anyway for thinking with me for a solution