# InnoDB: Bulk insert using transaction OR combine multiple queries?

Tags: mysql

When doing a bulk `INSERT` in InnoDB, should I use a transaction

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3);
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(4,5,6);
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(7,8,9);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Or combine multiple queries?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

If it matters, I'm using PHP and the MySQL database is on the same machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend combining multiple queries like you have in the bottom example.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

If either of the value-pair fails, none of the data will be inserted. This method also sends less characters and round-trip to the DB. The implication of less characters may not be that attractive but it still holds slight advantage.

EDIT:

Tim has a great question. Let me include information from [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-speed.html)

> If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time, use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements. If you are adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune the bulk_insert_buffer_size variable to make data insertion even faster.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have added information about execution speed

Comment: Interesting.  It appears that this was not necessarily the case with SQL Server for some reason.  So your recommendation then wins out in both cases.

Comment: Shadow has a great point about `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Same link I posted indicates that `LOAD DATA INFILE` may be much faster than `INSERT`

Comment: Just for future reference for myself, I'm including here an [answer from Martin Smith regarding SQL Server's 1000 inserts vs. insert with 1000 values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values)

Comment: This is exactly what I was reading, which prompted me to ask you for a clarification.  Fortunately, MySQL behaves the way one would expect, with minimal weirdness.

Comment: The link of "MySQL doc" is broken now. Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html instead.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st version is technically not bulk insert, you are inserting 1 record at a time. That's the slowest possible method to import large amount of data.

The 2nd option is called bulk insert and is a lot faster.

However, you can use transactions with bulk insert as well.

The 3rd option is to load data with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) command, which is even faster.

To speed up the insertion of massdata into innodb tables consider

- turning off autocommit mode
- turning off unique key checks
- turning off foreignkey checks

See [mysql documentation on these](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

Comment: Great point about `LOAD DATA INFILE` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-speed.html indicates this method as a very fast method for inserts.

Comment: I'm working with a 30 millions rows database, and doing massive data import with LOAD DATA I experimented unsuccesfully the "autocommit=0" method. The fastest method for me was to DROP all indexes, do the LOAD DATA and then rebuild indexes.

Comment: SQL Server likewise tends to be faster if you drop and rebuild the indexes.

Comment: @JonathanAllen mysql manual refers to multi-rows inserts as bulk inserts. MS SQL documentation may refer to the same as batch inserts, but since this question is about mysql, I'll follow the mysql terminology.