# scrapy insert into database

Tags: python, scrapy, database-performance

I have a working script using scrapy that inserts scraped items into a database using a pipelines class. However this seems to slow down the scrape considerably. I'm using the process item method to insert each scraped item into the database as it is scraped. Would it be faster to output the scraped items into a csv file and then use a stored procedure to insert the data into the database?

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    if 'address_line_1' in item:
        sql = """INSERT dbo.PropertyListings (date, url, ad_type, address_line_1, suburb, state, postcode)
        SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.PropertyListings
            WHERE date = ?
            AND address_line_1 = ?
            AND suburb = ?
            AND state = ?
            And postcode = ?
        )
        """
        self.crsr.execute(sql, item['date'], item['url'], item['ad_type'], item['address_line_1'], item['suburb'], \
            item['state'], item['postcode'], item['date'], item['address_line_1'], item['suburb'], item['state'], \
            item['postcode'])
        self.conn.commit()

    else:
        sql = """INSERT dbo.PropertyListings (date, url, ad_type, address_line_1, suburb, state, postcode)
        SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.PropertyListings
            WHERE date = ?
            AND url = ?
        )
        """

        self.crsr.execute(sql, item['date'], item['url'], item['ad_type'], '', item['suburb'], \
            item['state'], item['postcode'], item['date'], item['url'])
        self.conn.commit()

    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make an insert per data point. This is indeed very slow!! You should consider [bulk insertions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) after you've collected all of your data, or at least insert in chunks.

Use something like this

```
def scrape_me_good():
    data = []

    for something in something_else():
        # Process data
        data.append(process_a_something(something)

    bulk_insert(data)
```

Instead of this

```
def scrape_bad():
    for something in something_else():
        single_insert(process_a_something(something)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8640583/5491375) for quite a good breakdown of performance in SQL server