# INSERT INTO failing on SQL Fiddle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) for creating a test database.

My query is below:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE tblInputs (
    Type VARCHAR(256),
    Order_No VARCHAR(256),
    Planned_No VARCHAR(256),
    Purchase_No VARCHAR(256),
    Direction VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE Requirements (
    Order_No VARCHAR(256),
    Planned_No VARCHAR(256),
    Req_ID VARCHAR(256),
    Req_No VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE ReqRep (
    Req_ID VARCHAR(256),
    Req_No VARCHAR(256),
    Rep_ID VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE Replenishments (
    Rep_ID VARCHAR(256),
    Order_No VARCHAR(256),
    Planned_No VARCHAR(256),
    Purchase_No VARCHAR(256)
);


-- data
INSERT INTO tblInputs (Type, Direction, Order_No, Planned_No, Purchase_No)

SELECT 'Purchase', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124798', 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908851', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908852', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908853', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908854', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908855', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908853', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Build', 'O103916639', NULL, NULL, 'MIN' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Production', 'O103962037', NULL, NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Production', 'O103933200', NULL, NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL

INSERT INTO Requirements (Order_No, Planned_No, Req_ID, Req_No)
SELECT NULL, 'PL191908851', 'ABA', '36' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL191908852', 'CC',  '93' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL191908853', 'BBA', '27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL191908854', 'EWE', '42' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL191908855', 'WWW', '13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL191908856', 'EEE', '33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL191909922', 'GFW', '99' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL191910022', 'GFT', '23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'PL192010120', 'THE', '54' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103962037',  NULL, 'BDD', '37' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103933200',  NULL, 'DFA', '63' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103547812',  NULL, 'ADS', '45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103547415',  NULL, 'DWQ', '94' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103654787',  NULL, 'QZX', '96' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103214217',  NULL, 'NFD', '20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103215320',  NULL, 'GBV', '33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O106212219',  NULL, 'ERQ', '22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'O103215320',  NULL, 'MRP', '11' FROM DUAL

INSERT INTO ReqRep (Req_ID, Req_No, Repl_ID)
SELECT 'ABA', '36', '7736' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC', '93', '6686' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBA', '27', '5710' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EWE', '42', '7634' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'WWW', '13', '9393' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EEE', '33', '8442' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GFW', '99', '5758' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GFT', '23', '5988' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'THE', '54', '6748' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7124' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7125' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7126' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DFA', '63', '7125' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ADS', '45', '5855' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DWQ', '80', '9419' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'QZX', '96', '5748' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NFD', '20', '7055' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ERQ', '22', '7736' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MRP', '11', '7736' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GBV', '33', '9999' FROM DUAL

INSERT INTO Replenishments(Rep_ID, Order_No, Planned_No, Purchase_No)
SELECT '7736', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124799' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '6686', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5710', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124801' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7634', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124802' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '9393', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124803' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '8442', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124804' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5758', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124805' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5988', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124806' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '6748', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124807' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7123', 'O103654787', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7124', 'O103214217', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7125', 'O103215320', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7126', 'O106212219', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7125', 'O103215320', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5855', NULL, 'PL192010120', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '9419', NULL, 'PL121122221', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5748', NULL, 'PL272634123', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7055', NULL, 'PL983002032', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '9999', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124806' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1111', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124806' FROM DUAL
```

However, I am getting an error of:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I am simply trying to create a few tables for use in a later SO post.
The query up to this point works successfully:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE tblInputs (
    Type VARCHAR(256),
    Order_No VARCHAR(256),
    Planned_No VARCHAR(256),
    Purchase_No VARCHAR(256),
    Direction VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE Requirements (
    Order_No VARCHAR(256),
    Planned_No VARCHAR(256),
    Req_ID VARCHAR(256),
    Req_No VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE ReqRep (
    Req_ID VARCHAR(256),
    Req_No VARCHAR(256),
    Rep_ID VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE Replenishments (
    Rep_ID VARCHAR(256),
    Order_No VARCHAR(256),
    Planned_No VARCHAR(256),
    Purchase_No VARCHAR(256)
);


-- data
INSERT INTO tblInputs (Type, Direction, Order_No, Planned_No, Purchase_No)

SELECT 'Purchase', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124798', 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908851', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908852', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908853', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908854', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908855', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908853', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Build', 'O103916639', NULL, NULL, 'MIN' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Production', 'O103962037', NULL, NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Production', 'O103933200', NULL, NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
```

It fails on the second `INSERT INTO` statement.

I have reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values?noredirect=1&lq=1) but could not figure out a solution.

Comment: Semicolon after each insertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need  semicolon for each query

```
    INSERT INTO tblInputs (Type, Direction, Order_No, Planned_No, Purchase_No)

    SELECT 'Purchase', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124798', 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908851', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908852', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908853', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908854', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908855', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Planned', NULL, 'PL191908853', NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Build', 'O103916639', NULL, NULL, 'MIN' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Production', 'O103962037', NULL, NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Production', 'O103933200', NULL, NULL, 'PLUS' FROM DUAL7
    -- here
    ;


    INSERT INTO Requirements (Order_No, Planned_No, Req_ID, Req_No)
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191908851', 'ABA', '36' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191908852', 'CC',  '93' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191908853', 'BBA', '27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191908854', 'EWE', '42' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191908855', 'WWW', '13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191908856', 'EEE', '33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191909922', 'GFW', '99' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL191910022', 'GFT', '23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'PL192010120', 'THE', '54' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103962037',  NULL, 'BDD', '37' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103933200',  NULL, 'DFA', '63' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103547812',  NULL, 'ADS', '45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103547415',  NULL, 'DWQ', '94' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103654787',  NULL, 'QZX', '96' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103214217',  NULL, 'NFD', '20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103215320',  NULL, 'GBV', '33' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O106212219',  NULL, 'ERQ', '22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'O103215320',  NULL, 'MRP', '11' FROM DUAL
    -- here
    ;


    INSERT INTO ReqRep (Req_ID, Req_No, Repl_ID)
    SELECT 'ABA', '36', '7736' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CCC', '93', '6686' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BBA', '27', '5710' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'EWE', '42', '7634' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'WWW', '13', '9393' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'EEE', '33', '8442' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GFW', '99', '5758' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GFT', '23', '5988' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'THE', '54', '6748' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7124' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7125' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BDD', '37', '7126' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DFA', '63', '7125' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ADS', '45', '5855' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DWQ', '80', '9419' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'QZX', '96', '5748' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'NFD', '20', '7055' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ERQ', '22', '7736' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MRP', '11', '7736' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GBV', '33', '9999' FROM DUAL
    -- here
    ;


    INSERT INTO Replenishments(Rep_ID, Order_No, Planned_No, Purchase_No)
    SELECT '7736', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124799' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '6686', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '5710', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124801' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '7634', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124802' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9393', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124803' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '8442', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124804' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '5758', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124805' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '5988', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124806' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '6748', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124807' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '7123', 'O103654787', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '7124', 'O103214217', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '7125', 'O103215320', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '7126', 'O106212219', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '7125', 'O103215320', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '5855', NULL, 'PL192010120', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9419', NULL, 'PL121122221', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '5748', NULL, 'PL272634123', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '7055', NULL, 'PL983002032', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9999', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124806' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '1111', NULL, NULL, 'PO9000124806' FROM DUAL
    -- here
    ;
```

Comment: I couldn't at the time, needed to wait 10 minutes. SO rules, not mine =)

Comment: @JerryM.  Im sorry I did not think that this rule also applied to those with such a high reputation ..