# Fastest way to insert multiple values into a table from pyobdc

Tags: python, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm using pyobdc with an application that requires me to insert >1000 rows normally which I currently do individually with pyobdc. Though this tends to take >30 minutes to finish. I was wondering if there are any faster methods that could do this < 1 minute. I know you can use multiple values in an insert commands but according to this ([Multiple INSERT statements vs. single INSERT with multiple VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values)) it would possibly be even slower.
The code currently looks like this.

```
def Insert_X(X_info):
        columns = ', '.join(X_info.keys())
        placeholders = ', '.join('?' * len(X_info.keys()))
        columns = columns.replace("'","")
        values = [x for x in X_info.values()]
        query_string = f"INSERT INTO X ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders});"
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query_string,values)
```

With Insert_X being called >1000 times.

Comment: can you provide some sample code?

Comment: @Charlieface thank you for the comment I was wondering what you meant by parameterization as I was using bound parameters in the above code.

Comment: Consider using a Table-Valued parameter or bulk-insert, I don't know if pyodbc supports either of these, but they are both very fast. 30 min is an age for 1000 rows whichever way you cut it, I wonder if you have some other problem (slow CPU or HDD?)