# Insert Data into MySQL in multiple Tables in C# efficiently

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

I need to insert a huge CSV-File into 2 Tables with a 1:n relationship within a mySQL Database.

The CSV-file comes weekly and has about 1GB, which needs to be append to the existing data.
Each of them 2 tables have a Auto increment Primary Key.

I've tried:

- Entity Framework (takes most time of all approaches)
- Datasets (same)
- Bulk Upload (doesn't support multiple tables)
- MySqlCommand with Parameters (needs to be nested, my current approach)
- MySqlCommand with StoredProcedure including a Transaction

Any further suggestions?

Let's say simplified this is my datastructure:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

I need to insert from the csv into this database:

```
       User   (1-n)   Code     
+---+-----+-----+ +---+---+-----+        
|PID|FName|LName| |CID|PID|Code | 
+---+-----+-----+ +---+---+-----+
| 1 |Jon  | Foo | | 1 | 1 | ed3 | 
| 2 |Max  | Foo | | 2 | 1 | wst | 
| 3 |Paul | Foo | | 3 | 2 | xsd | 
+---+-----+-----+ +---+---+-----+
```

Here a sample line of the CSV-file

```
Jon;Foo;ed3,wst
```

A Bulk load like `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is not possible because i have restricted writing rights

Comment: Can you elaborate on "(doesn't support multiple tables).  Why can't you bulk insert one file at a time?  By the way, `INSERT INTO` with params is extremely slow compared to bulk insert.

Comment: I would suggest a bulk upload to a temporary folder which can be done pretty fast, and then with a MySQL stored procedure you can split the data to the `User` and `Code` tables. Using a stored procedure will be much faster than any C# solution.

Comment: When you say dynamic amount you mean the `1-N` relation of the data? If so, I can't see what the issue would be. Could you please provide the source data for the sample you gave?

Comment: @fubo can you alter the tables structure ? like add & drop a column ?

Comment: @SirajMansour - no, there are other applications using this database / tables

Comment: @SirajMansour: If you are looking to drop a column, then you will also drop the data of that column which is already present in the table. This defeats all purpose.

Comment: @fubo i am not looking to tamper an existing column, i can show how to solve the problem with adding a column temporarily and removing it after the insertion of the data is done

Comment: @displayName i am not going to touch the existing columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the great size of data, the best approach (performance wise) is to leave as much data processing to the database and not the application.

Create a temporary table that the data from the .csv file will be temporarily saved.

```
CREATE TABLE `imported` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `codes` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Loading the data from the `.csv` to this table is pretty straightforward. I would suggest the use of `MySqlCommand` (which is also your current approach). Also, **using the same** `MySqlConnection` object for all `INSERT` statements **will reduce the total execution time**.

Then to furthermore process the data, you can create a stored procedure that will handle it.

Assuming these two tables (taken from your simplified example):

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `PID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3737 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `codes` (
  `CID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

you can have the following stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `import_data`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE fname VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE lname VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE codesstr VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE splitted_value VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE newid INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE occurance INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT firstname,lastname,codes FROM imported;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;

    import_loop: 
        LOOP FETCH cur INTO fname, lname, codesstr;
            IF done = 1 THEN
                LEAVE import_loop;
            END IF;

            INSERT INTO users (FName,LName) VALUES (fname, lname);
            SET newid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

            SET i=1;
            SET occurance = (SELECT LENGTH(codesstr) - LENGTH(REPLACE(codesstr, ',', '')) + 1);

            WHILE i <= occurance DO
                SET splitted_value =
                    (SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(codesstr, ',', i),
                    LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(codesstr, ',', i - 1)) + 1), ',', ''));

                INSERT INTO codes (PID, code) VALUES (newid, splitted_value);
                SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END
```

For every row in the source data, it makes an `INSERT` statement for the `user` table. Then there is a `WHILE` loop to split the comma separated codes and make for each one an `INSERT` statement for the `codes` table.

Regarding the use of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, it is reliable on a PER CONNECTION basis ([see doc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)). If the MySQL connection used to run this stored procedure is not used by other transactions, the use of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is safe.

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

**Edit**: Here is the OP's variant that omits the temp-table `imported`. Instead of inserting the data from the .csv to the `imported` table, you call the SP to directly store them to your database.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `import_data`(IN fname VARCHAR(255), IN lname VARCHAR(255),IN codesstr VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE splitted_value VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE newid INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE occurance INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    INSERT INTO users (FName,LName) VALUES (fname, lname);
    SET newid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    SET i=1;
    SET occurance = (SELECT LENGTH(codesstr) - LENGTH(REPLACE(codesstr, ',', '')) + 1);

    WHILE i <= occurance DO
        SET splitted_value =
            (SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(codesstr, ',', i),
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(codesstr, ',', i - 1)) + 1), ',', ''));

        INSERT INTO codes (PID, code) VALUES (newid, splitted_value);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

**Note**: The code to split the codes is taken from [here](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/) (MySQL does not provide a split function for strings).

Comment: Great one! That's also possible and even faster without temp-table `CREATE DEFINER=\`root\`@\`localhost\` PROCEDURE \`import_data\`(IN fname VARCHAR(255), IN lname VARCHAR(255),IN codesstr VARCHAR(255))`

Comment: is that safe? `SET newid = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: @Byyo that is a good point. It is thread safe, I updated my answer with the related information

Comment: @fubo that is a great idea! Yes, omitting the temp table can make the execution faster. I believe though, if you had the option to BULK import the .csv data my SP would perform faster. But in any scenario, one should test and see how both approaches perform.

Answer (score 7):

Referring to your answer i would replace

```
using (MySqlCommand myCmdNested = new MySqlCommand(cCommand, mConnection))
{
    foreach (string Code in item.Codes)
    {
        myCmdNested.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@UserID", UID));
        myCmdNested.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Code", Code));
        myCmdNested.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

with

```
List<string> lCodes = new List<string>();
foreach (string code in item.Codes)
{
    lCodes.Add(String.Format("('{0}','{1}')", UID, MySqlHelper.EscapeString(code)));
}
string cCommand = "INSERT INTO Code (UserID, Code) VALUES " + string.Join(",", lCodes);
using (MySqlCommand myCmdNested = new MySqlCommand(cCommand, mConnection))
{
    myCmdNested.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

that generates one insert statement instead of `item.Count`

Comment: @fubo: This answer describes what the `InsertInto` method will look like.

Answer (score 3):

I developed my WPF application application using the Entity Framework and used SQL server database and needed to read data from an excel file and had to insert that data into 2 tables that has relationship between them. For roughly about 15000 rows in excel it used to take around 4 hours of time. Then what I did was I used a block of 500 rows per insert and this speeded up my insertion to unbelievalbe fast and now it takes mere 3-5 seconds to import that same data.

So I would suggest you add your rows to a Context like 100/200/500 at a time and then call the SaveChanges method (if you really want to be using EF). There are other helpful tips as well to speed up the performance for EF. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework) for your reference.

```
var totalRecords = TestPacksData.Rows.Count;
var totalPages = (totalRecords / ImportRecordsPerPage) + 1;
while (count <= totalPages)
{
     var pageWiseRecords = TestPacksData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(count * ImportRecordsPerPage).Take(ImportRecordsPerPage);
     count++;
     Project.CreateNewSheet(pageWiseRecords.ToList());
     Project.CreateNewSpool(pageWiseRecords.ToList());
}
```

And here is the CreateNewSheet method

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new Sheet record in the database
/// </summary>
/// <param name="row">DataRow containing the Sheet record</param>
public void CreateNewSheet(List<DataRow> rows)
{
     var tempSheetsList = new List<Sheet>();
     foreach (var row in rows)
     {
         var sheetNo = row[SheetFields.Sheet_No.ToString()].ToString();
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sheetNo))
              continue;
         var testPackNo = row[SheetFields.Test_Pack_No.ToString()].ToString();
         TestPack testPack = null;
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testPackNo))
              testPack = GetTestPackByTestPackNo(testPackNo);

         var existingSheet = GetSheetBySheetNo(sheetNo);
         if (existingSheet != null)
         {
             UpdateSheet(existingSheet, row);
             continue;
         }

         var isometricNo = GetIsometricNoFromSheetNo(sheetNo);
         var newSheet = new Sheet
         {
             sheet_no = sheetNo,
             isometric_no = isometricNo,
             ped_rev = row[SheetFields.PED_Rev.ToString()].ToString(),
             gpc_rev = row[SheetFields.GPC_Rev.ToString()].ToString()
         };
         if (testPack != null)
         {
             newSheet.test_pack_id = testPack.id;
             newSheet.test_pack_no = testPack.test_pack_no;
         }
         if (!tempSheetsList.Any(l => l.sheet_no == newSheet.sheet_no))
         {
              DataStore.Context.Sheets.Add(newSheet);
              tempSheetsList.Add(newSheet);
         }
   }
   try
   {
        DataStore.Context.SaveChanges();
        **DataStore.Dispose();** This is very important. Dispose the context
   }
   catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
   {
       // Create log for the exception here
   }
}
```

CreateNewSpool is ditto same method except for the fields name and table name, because it updates a child table. But the idea is the same

Comment: The insert for the second table needs the ID / Foreign Key of the first table. How does EF does this internal without inserting each row seperate? +1 for the reference to the other question

Comment: When you do the insert in the parent table, get the id/foreign key value and then use it to insert the value in the child table. Thats exactly what I did and my performance was to my liking (4-5 seconds)

Answer (score 2):

1 - Add a column VirtualId to `User` table & class.

**EDITED**
2 - Assign numbers in a loop for the VirtualId (use negative numbers starting -1 to avoid collisions in the last step) field in each `User` Object. For each `Code c` object belonging to `User u` object set the `c.UserId = u.VirtualId`.

3 - Bulk load Users into `User` table, Bulk load Codes into `Code` table.

4- `UPDATE CODE C,USER U SET C.UserId = U.Id WHERE C.UserId = U.VirtualId.`

NOTE : If you have a FK Constraint on Code.UserId you can drop it and re-add it after the Insert.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int VirtualId { get; set; }

}

public class Code
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is why you should add a VirtualID column, you probably missed my point, you leave the ID there as it is, you don't touch it, all you need is to add the VirtualID column and assign values to it

Comment: @fubo We've used this method in production for cases more complex than yours, try it out, it is the fastest we could find when it comes to a large dataset.

Comment: @fubo the field UserId in the Code Object/Table not the same one in 'User' Object, take a look at the class structures above. See my edit for step 2

Comment: @fubo you don't get my approach, i will draw a table with data as an example for you.

Comment: @fubo great, this is the fastest approach among all the suggested. Please give me your feedback if you ever try it

Answer (score 0):

Can you break the CSV into two files?

E.g. Suppose your file has the following columns:

```
... A ... | ... B ... 
a0 | b0
a0 | b1
a0 | b2    <-- data
a1 | b3
a1 | b4
```

So one set of A might have multiple B entries.  After you break it apart, you get:

```
... A ...
a0
a1

... B ...
b0
b1
b2
b3
b4
```

Then you bulk insert them separately.

Edit: Pseudo code

Based on the conversation, something like:

```
DataTable tableA = ...; // query schema for TableA
DataTable tableB = ...; // query schmea for TableB

List<String> usernames = select distinct username from TableA;
Hashtable htUsername = new Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
foreach (String username in usernames)
     htUsername[username] = "";

int colUsername = ...;
foreach (String[] row in CSVFile) {
    String un = row[colUsername] as String;
    if (htUsername[un] == null) {
        // add new row to tableA
        DataRow row = tableA.NewRow();
        row["Username"] = un;
        // etc.
        tableA.Rows.Add(row);
        htUsername[un] = "";
    }
}

// bulk insert TableA

select userid, username from TableA
Hashtable htUserId = new Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
// htUserId[username] = userid;

int colUserId = ...;

foreach (String[] row in CSVFile) {

    String un = row[colUsername] as String;
    int userid = (int) htUserId[un];
    DataRow row = tableB.NewRow();
    row[colUserId] = userId;
    // fill in other values
    tableB.Rows.Add(row);
    if (table.Rows.Count == 65000) {
        // bulk insert TableB
        var t = tableB.Clone();
        tableB.Dispose();
        tableB = t;
    }
}

if (tableB.Rows.Count > 0)
    // bulk insert TableB
```

Comment: Based on the primary keys of Table A.  If there are no primary keys then decide which columns form a unique A.

Comment: So you have auto-increment columns that are your primary keys?

Comment: Are the tables truncated before the bulk insert?  Or is the csv appended to existing data?

Comment: auto-increment columns - YES, are the tables truncated before the bulk insert - NO

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the insertions done in a table are sequential while the insertions in different table can be done in parallel. Open two separate *new* connections to the same database and then insert in parallel maybe by using Task Parallel Library.

However, if there are integrity constraints about 1:n relationship between the tables, then:

1. Insertions might fail and thus *any* parallel insert approach would be wrong. Clearly then your best bet would be to do sequential inserts only, one table after the other.
2. You can try and sort the data of both tables write the `InsertInto` method written below such that insert in second table will happen only after you are done inserting the data in the first one.

**Edit:** Since you have requested, if there is a possibility for you to perform the inserts in parallel, following is the code *template* you can use.

```
private void ParallelInserts()
{
    ..
    //Other code in the method
    ..

    //Read first csv into memory. It's just a GB so should be fine
    ReadFirstCSV();

    //Read second csv into memory...
    ReadSecondCSV();

    //Because the inserts will last more than a few CPU cycles...
    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.None)

    //An array to hold the two parallel inserts
    var insertTasks = new Task[2];

    //Begin insert into first table...
    insertTasks[0] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => InsertInto(commandStringFirst, connectionStringFirst));

    //Begin insert into second table...
    insertTasks[1] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => InsertInto(commandStringSecond, connectionStringSecond));

    //Let them be done...
    Task.WaitAll(insertTasks);

    Console.WriteLine("Parallel insert finished.");
}


//Defining the InsertInto method which we are passing to the tasks in the method above
private static void InsertInto(string commandString, string connectionString)
{
    using (/*open a new connection using the connectionString passed*/)
    {
        //In a while loop, iterate until you have 100/200/500 rows
        while (fileIsNotExhausted)
        {
            using (/*commandString*/)
            {
                //Execute command to insert in bulk
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might not work if there are integrity constraints on the 1:n relationship

Comment: @JonKloske: in that case, only sequential insert of tables is possible. And when we insert in a table, the inserts are always queued. Therefore all the user can do is wait. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problems - what you suggest can still work, you just have to make sure that the inserts into the dependent table happen strictly after the corresponding row in the parent table has been inserted.

Comment: @fubo: Let me know if you are stuck again. I will try to get some workaround. I really like the parallel approach.

Comment: @fubo: The comment that I put above while loop in the `InsertInto` method, for taking 100/200/500 rows is for having the inserts in bulk. To maintain 1-to-n relation, this number can be modified such that we first insert the `1` part in main table and then insert the `n` part in the referenceing table.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "efficiently" are you talking memory, or time?

In terms of improving the speed of the inserts, if you can do multiple value blocks per insert statement, you can get 500% improvement in speed. I did some benchmarks on this over in this question: [Which is faster: multiple single INSERTs or one multiple-row INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793169/which-is-faster-multiple-single-inserts-or-one-multiple-row-insert/10276827#10276827)

My approach is described in the answer, but simply put, reading in up to say 50 "rows" (to be inserted) at once and bundling them into a single `INSERT INTO(...), VALUES(...),(...),(...)...(...),(...)` type statement seems to really speed things up. At least, if you're restricted from not being able to bulk load.

Another approach btw if you have live data you can't drop indexes on during the upload, is to create a memory table on the mysql server without indexes, dump the data there, and then do an `INSERT INTO live SELECT * FROM mem`. Though that uses more memory on the server, hence the question at the start of this answer about "what do you mean by 'efficiently'?" :)

Oh, and there's probably nothing wrong with iterating through the file and doing all the first table inserts first, and then doing the second table ones. Unless the data is being used live, I guess. In that case you could definitely still use the bundled approach, but the application logic to do that is a lot more complex.

**UPDATE:** OP requested example C# code for multivalue insert blocks.

Note: this code assumes you have a number of structures already configured:

1. **tables** *List<string>* - table names to insert into
2. **fieldslist** *Dictionary<string, List<String>>* - list of field names for each table
3. **typeslist** *Dictionary<string, List<MySqlDbType>>* - list of `MySqlDbType`s for each table, same order as the field names.
4. **nullslist** *Dictionary<string, List<Boolean>>* - list of flags to tell if a field is nullable or not, for each table (same order as field names).
5. **prikey** *Dictionary<string, string>* - list of primary key field name, per table (note: this doesn't support multiple field primary keys, though if you needed it you could probably hack it in - I think somewhere I have a version that does support this, but... meh).
6. **theData** *Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<int, object>>>* - the actual data, as a list of fieldnum-value dictionaries, per table.

Oh yeah, and the localcommand is MySqlCommand created by using CreateCommand() on the local MySqlConnection object.

Further note: I wrote this quite a while back when I was kind of starting. If this causes your eyes or brain to bleed, I apologise in advance :)

```
const int perinsert = 50;
foreach (string table in tables)
{
    string[] fields = fieldslist[table].ToArray();
    MySqlDbType[] types = typeslist[table].ToArray();
    bool[] nulls = nullslist[table].ToArray();

    int thisblock = perinsert;
    int rowstotal = theData[table].Count;
    int rowsremainder = rowstotal % perinsert;
    int rowscopied = 0;

    // Do the bulk (multi-VALUES block) INSERTs, but only if we have more rows than there are in a single bulk insert to perform:
    while (rowscopied < rowstotal)
    {
        if (rowstotal - rowscopied < perinsert)
            thisblock = rowstotal - rowscopied;
        // Generate a 'perquery' multi-VALUES prepared INSERT statement:
        List<string> extravals = new List<string>();
        for (int j = 0; j < thisblock; j++)
            extravals.Add(String.Format("(@{0}_{1})", j, String.Join(String.Format(", @{0}_", j), fields)));
        localcmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES{1}", tmptable, String.Join(",", extravals.ToArray()));
        // Now create the parameters to match these:
        for (int j = 0; j < thisblock; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                localcmd.Parameters.Add(String.Format("{0}_{1}", j, fields[i]), types[i]).IsNullable = nulls[i];

        // Keep doing bulk INSERTs until there's less rows left than we need for another one:
        while (rowstotal - rowscopied >= thisblock)
        {
            // Queue up all the VALUES for this block INSERT:
            for (int j = 0; j < thisblock; j++)
            {
                Dictionary<int, object> row = theData[table][rowscopied++];
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                    localcmd.Parameters[String.Format("{0}_{1}", j, fields[i])].Value = row[i];
            }
            // Run the query:
            localcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        // Clear all the paramters - we're done here:
        localcmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? The benchmark was in C#, so... yeah. Basically it involves a loop where I add fieldname.i as the parameter into a query for each field, and then for each row (i), then I go and fill in those fieldnames for each of the actual rows of data to insert. Then I have a massive prepared query with multiple values.

Comment: so much work, not a single unicorn dollar in return! :D