# Single INSERT command of multiple rows vs. multiple INSERT commands of single rows

Tags: mysql, insert

I would like to know which solution is faster than the other. 
So, imagine we'd like to INSERT 10000 rows into a table. We have the following 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:**
Run the INSERT query 10000 times:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (a,b,c) VALUES ("a","b","c"); x 10000
```

**Solution 2:**
Run one INSERT query with 10000 rows at once:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (a,b,c) VALUES 
("a","b","c"),
("a","b","c"),
("a","b","c"),
 ...,
("a","b","c");
```

Comment: Please check the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793169/which-is-faster-multiple-single-inserts-or-one-multiple-row-insert

Answer (score 1):

Solution 2 : it need just one connection to the database, the solution 1 need 1000 connections and it's so mush.

Comment: What if we run all 10000 `INSERT`s with one connection? 1. open connection; 2. perform 10000 `INSERT`s ; 3. close connection

Comment: you can do for exemple a loop and insert 1000 by 1000

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 is around 10 times slower than solution 2.

From the guy with the mysql database server with 100gb data and 5000 request per second.