# Batch update in knex

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I'd like to perform a batch update using [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/)

For example:

```
'UPDATE foo SET [theValues] WHERE idFoo = 1'
'UPDATE foo SET [theValues] WHERE idFoo = 2'
```

with values:

```
{ name: "FooName1", checked: true } // to `idFoo = 1`
{ name: "FooName2", checked: false } // to `idFoo = 2`
```

I was using [node-mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries) previously, which allowed multiple-statements. While using that I simply built a mulitple-statement query string and just send that through the wire in a single run.

I'm not sure how to achieve the same with Knex. I can see `batchInsert` as an API method I can use, but nothing as far as `batchUpdate` is concerned.

#### Note:

- I can do an async iteration and update each row separately. That's bad cause it means there's gonna be lots of roundtrips from the server to the DB
- I can use the `raw()` thing of Knex and probably do something similar to what I do with node-mysql. However that defeats the whole knex purpose of being a DB abstraction layer (It introduces strong DB coupling)

So I'd like to do this using something "knex-y".

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Why not do parallel async operations? It consumes a bit more RAM because you're registering a callback for each update but from the network card's point of view it just looks like one big stream of updates.

Comment: @slebetman doesn't sound bad - I'll give it a shot and if it looks good, I'll post an answer

Comment: @slebetman Revisiting this after 1.5 years. Back then, I've went with your solution instead of what I accepted and it worked great. If you ever come around to writing an answer I'll accept yours instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I needed to perform a batch update inside a transaction (I didn't want to have partial updates in case something went wrong).
I've resolved it the next way:

```
// I wrap knex as 'connection'
return connection.transaction(trx => {
    const queries = [];
    users.forEach(user => {
        const query = connection('users')
            .where('id', user.id)
            .update({
                lastActivity: user.lastActivity,
                points: user.points,
            })
            .transacting(trx); // This makes every update be in the same transaction
        queries.push(query);
    });

    Promise.all(queries) // Once every query is written
        .then(trx.commit) // We try to execute all of them
        .catch(trx.rollback); // And rollback in case any of them goes wrong
});
```

Comment: When using mssql, if you try Promise.all(queries), tedious (the NodeJS mssql library) will error out with `Can't acquire connection for the request. There is another request in progress.` and Knex follows up with `Can't rollback transaction. There is a request in progress.`. This is because Promise.all() executes all queries in parallel.

To fix this, all promises must be resolved one after another. You can do this with code [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence).

Comment: [Also see this bug report from Tedious](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/491)

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, but I struggled with data not being written to db; it turns out I needed to replace `.then(trx.commit)` and `.catch(trx.rollback)` with arrow functions: `.then(() => trx.commit)` and `.catch(() => trx.rollback)`

Comment: @RedShift, I'm getting Error `Can't acquire connection for the request. There is another request in progress`. Checked the link provided by you. Can you provide  simple example.

Comment: users is not defined.. where did you get users from?

Comment: @justdvl `users` isn't defined, but it would look like a collection of user objects.

Comment: @RedShift your point about `Promise.all()` executing all queries in parallel seemed to be right for my problem. Solved it by following the thread you linked, thanks!

Answer (score 28):

Assuming you have a collection of valid keys/values for the given table:

```
// abstract transactional batch update
function batchUpdate(table, collection) {
  return knex.transaction(trx => {
    const queries = collection.map(tuple =>
      knex(table)
        .where('id', tuple.id)
        .update(tuple)
        .transacting(trx)
    );
    return Promise.all(queries)
      .then(trx.commit)    
      .catch(trx.rollback);
  });
}
```

To call it

```
batchUpdate('user', [...]);
```

---

Are you unfortunately subject to non-conventional column names? No worries, I got you fam:

```
function batchUpdate(options, collection) {
  return knex.transaction(trx => {
    const queries = collection.map(tuple =>
      knex(options.table)
        .where(options.column, tuple[options.column])
        .update(tuple)
        .transacting(trx)
    );
    return Promise.all(queries)
      .then(trx.commit)    
      .catch(trx.rollback);
  });
}
```

To call it

```
batchUpdate({ table: 'user', column: 'user_id' }, [...]);
```

Modern Syntax Version:

```
const batchUpdate = async (options, collection) => {
  const { table, column } = options;
  const trx = await knex.transaction(); 
  try {
    await Promise.all(collection.map(tuple => 
      knex(table)
        .where(column, tuple[column])
        .update(tuple)
        .transacting(trx)
      )
    );
    await trx.commit();
  } catch (error) {
    await trx.rollback();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, just curious, how can I customize this if I want to return all id after commit

Comment: Added my snippet below to return an array of ID values. Hope it helps!

Comment: Nothing big changes only removing Primary key column from updated column list       ```collection.map((tuple) => {
        const data = { ...tuple };
        delete data[column];
        return knex(table).where(column, tuple[column]).update(data).transacting(trx);
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 20):

You have a good idea of the pros and cons of each approach. I would recommend a raw query that bulk updates over several async updates. Yes you can run them in parallel, but your bottleneck becomes the time it takes for the db to run each update. Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793169/which-is-faster-multiple-single-inserts-or-one-multiple-row-insert).

Below is an example of an batch upsert using knex.raw. Assume that records is an array of objects (one obj for each row we want to update) whose values are the properties names line up with the columns in the database you want to update:

```
var knex = require('knex'),
    _ = require('underscore');

function bulkUpdate (records) {
      var updateQuery = [
          'INSERT INTO mytable (primaryKeyCol, col2, colN) VALUES',
          _.map(records, () => '(?)').join(','),
          'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE',
          'col2 = VALUES(col2),',
          'colN = VALUES(colN)'
      ].join(' '),

      vals = [];

      _(records).map(record => {
          vals.push(_(record).values());
      });

      return knex.raw(updateQuery, vals);
 }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276827/3199310) answer does a great job explaining the runtime relationship between the two approaches.

Edit:

It was requested that I show what `records` would look like in this example.

```
var records = [
  { primaryKeyCol: 123, col2: 'foo', colN: 'bar' },
  { // some other record, same props }
];
```

Please note that if your `record` has additional properties than the ones you specified in the query, you cannot do:

```
  _(records).map(record => {
      vals.push(_(record).values());
  });
```

Because you will hand too many values to the query per record and knex will fail to match the property values of each record with the `?` characters in the query. You instead will need to explicitly push the values on each record that you want to insert into an array like so:

```
  // assume a record has additional property `type` that you dont want to
  // insert into the database
  // example: { primaryKeyCol: 123, col2: 'foo', colN: 'bar', type: 'baz' }
  _(records).map(record => {
      vals.push(record.primaryKeyCol);
      vals.push(record.col2);
      vals.push(record.colN);
  });
```

There are less repetitive ways of doing the above explicit references, but this is just an example. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, can you provide a sample structure of the "records"? just to be sure that I'm doing the correct one thanks!

Comment: @IamL Answered your question in an edit. Let me know if that helps you. :) If so, please upvote, if not I can explain further!

Comment: what if i've a different example `{ primaryKeyCol: 123, col2: {status: 'available, offline: false, etc .... props'}}` and does primaryKeyCol must be the primary key in my table , can't i update for email or something i know it's unique but it doesn't have the unique constraint. how do i update such a thing

Comment: @PatrickMotard i get this error when i try to do it with your code `Error: Expected 1191 bindings, saw 397
    at replaceRawArrBindings`

Comment: using insert...on duplicate key update to just do updates this way has the flaw that it will actually insert if you mistakenly include a primary key that doesn't exist.  an alternative on mysql 8.0.19+/mariadb 10.3+ is using a values table constructor https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9b320de7516ac3cac1b787c4d314049

Comment: This code is unfortunately not transaction safe. I also recommend the native JS `map` function over importing `underscore` for just `_.map`.

Comment: Agreed @jiminikiz, I also no longer use underscore. The native JS methods are sufficient now.

Comment: A transaction would be a great addition to this solution. Other answers here illustrate using transactions in the context of promises. Good point @jiminikiz!

Answer (score 0):

The solution works great for me! I just include an ID parameter to make it dynamic across tables with custom ID tags. Chenhai, here's my snippet including a way to return a single array of ID values for the transaction:

```
function batchUpdate(table, id, collection) {
   return knex.transaction((trx) => {
       const queries = collection.map(async (tuple) => {
       const [tupleId] = await knex(table)
        .where(`${id}`, tuple[id])
        .update(tuple)
        .transacting(trx)
        .returning(id);

       return tupleId;
   });

   return Promise.all(queries).then(trx.commit).catch(trx.rollback);
   });
}
```

You can use 
    `response = await batchUpdate("table_name", "custom_table_id", [array of rows to update])` 
to get the returned array of IDs.

Comment: You don't need `async` nor `await ` in your `collection.map`. Just return `knex.update`. `Promise.all` takes an array of Promises.

Answer (score -1):

The update can be done in batches, i.e **1000 rows** in a batch

And as long as it does it in batches, **the bluebird map** could be used.

For more information on bluebird map: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html

```
const limit = 1000;
const totalRows = 50000;
const seq = count => Array(Math.ceil(count / limit)).keys();

map(seq(totalRows), page => updateTable(dbTable, page), { concurrency: 1 });

const updateTable = async (dbTable, page) => {
let offset = limit* page;

return knex(dbTable).pluck('id').limit(limit).offset(offset).then(ids => {
    return knex(dbTable)
        .whereIn('id', ids)
        .update({ date: new Date() })
        .then((rows) => {
            console.log(`${page} - Updated rows of the table ${dbTable} from ${offset} to ${offset + batch}: `, rows);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log({ err });
        });
})
.catch((err) => {
       console.log({ err });
 });
};
```

Where **pluck()** is used to get ids in array form

Comment: You're swallowing errors. Don't handle `catch`, otherwise your script will keep going if updates failed. Your outer `.catch` won't trigger either since your inner `.catch` is console.logging and not throwing errors.

Comment: The outer `catch` is for `pluck('id').limit(limit).offset(offset)` and
the inner `catch` is for `update()`. Thanks

Comment: I understand that, what I'm saying is that you're dangerously handling errors.