# How to add multiple rows using "Insert ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" using knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

so I've been playing around with knex lately, however I found myself on a situation where I don't know what to do anymore.

so I have this query:

```
knex.raw("INSERT INTO tablename (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(`col2`)", 
[
    ['val1', 'hello', 'world'],
    ['val2', 'ohayo', 'minasan'],
]);
```

And for some reasons It throws me an error `Expected 2 bindings, saw 3`.

I tried making it:

```
knex.raw("INSERT INTO tablename (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(`col2`)", 
    ['val1', 'hello', 'world'],
    ['val2', 'ohayo', 'minasan'],
);
```

No error this time, but it only inserts the first array.

I also tried making the values an object:

```
[
    {col1: 'val1', col2: 'hello', col3: 'world'},
    {col1: 'val2', col2: 'ohayo', col3: 'minasan'},
]
```

But still no luck.

Comment: Checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543668/batch-update-in-knex
They Show you how to do it.

Comment: yep, I already checked that, in fact I commented on the answer regarding the data structure of the "records" since it is not quite clear what it looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to insert a fix number rows at a time, you could try this:

```
knex.raw("INSERT INTO tablename (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(`col2`)", 
    ['val1', 'hello', 'world', 'val2', 'ohayo', 'minasan'],
);
```

If you don't know how many you need to insert at a time, it is possible to write a script that adds `(?, ?, ?),` as many times as needed.

```
var questionMarks = "";
var values = [];
var rows = [
    {col1: 'val1', col2: 'hello', col3: 'world'},
    {col1: 'val2', col2: 'ohayo', col3: 'minasan'},
];
rows.forEach(function(value, index){
    questionMarks += "("
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(x){
         questionMarks += "?, ";
         values.push(value[x]);
    });
    questionMarks = questionMarks.substr(0, questionMarks.length - 2);
    questionMarks += "), ";
});
questionMarks = questionMarks.substr(0, questionMarks.length - 2); //cut off last unneeded comma and space
knex.raw("INSERT INTO tablename (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES " + questionMarks + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(`col2`)", values);
```

Comment: I'm including a script to calculate how much `(?, ?, ?), ` is needed.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thanks! I will just use loops to add (?, ?, ?) and array push for the values since I don't know the exact number of rows to be inserted.

Comment: @IamL If you get stuck, check out the addition.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote this code to insert/update either a single row as an object or multiple rows as an array of objects:

```
function insertOrUpdate(knex: Knex, tableName: string, data: any) {
  const firstData = data[0] ? data[0] : data;
  return knex.raw(knex(tableName).insert(data).toQuery() + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(firstData).map((field) => `${field}=VALUES(${field})`).join(", "));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Nathan's solution won't work if you are using PostgreSQL, as there is no `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. So in PostgreSQL you should use `ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET` :

```
const insertOrUpdate = (knex, tableName, data) => {
  const firstData = data[0] ? data[0] : data;

  return knex().raw(
    knex(tableName).insert(data).toQuery() + ' ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET ' +
      Object.keys(firstData).map((field) => `${field}=EXCLUDED.${field}`).join(', ')
  );
};
```

If you are using `Objection.js` (knex's wrapper) then (and don't forget to import knex in this case):

```
const insertOrUpdate = (model, tableName, data) => {
  const firstData = data[0] ? data[0] : data;

  return model.knex().raw(
    knex(tableName).insert(data).toQuery() + ' ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET ' +
      Object.keys(firstData).map((field) => `${field}=EXCLUDED.${field}`).join(', ')
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2022 Update

I now use [onConflict](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#onconflict) for this one.
This will work for PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite databases

Let's say I have a table with Primary key or unique Key called `key` and `value`

#### How to use it:

```
await knex('workspaces_settings')
  .insert({
    key,
    value,
    created_at: new Date(),
    updated_at: new Date(),
  })
  .onConflict(['key', 'value'])
  .merge();
```

This will make it so if the key-value combination exist, it would simply update the values based on the field inside the `insert` function.

#### For multiple values

You simply just need to pass an array in the `insert` instead:

```
await knex('workspaces_settings')
  .insert([
    {
      key: '1',
      value: '1',
      created_at: new Date(),
      updated_at: new Date(),
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      value: '2',
      created_at: new Date(),
      updated_at: new Date(),
    },
  ])
  .onConflict(['key', 'value'])
  .merge();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const db = knex({/* config */});

const records = [
  { id: "1", col1: "hello", col2: "world"],
  { id: "2", col1: "ohayo", col2: "minasan"]
];

const { sql, bindings } = db.table("table").insert(records).toSQL();

// MySQL
// --------------
await db.raw(
  ` ${sql} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    col1 = VALUES(col1),
    col2 = VALUES(col2)`,
  bindings
);

// PostgreSQL
// --------------
await db.raw(
  ` ${sql} ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE
    SET col1 = EXCLUDED.col1,
        col2 = EXCLUDED.col2`,
  bindings
);
```