# knex update multiple rows in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

Is it possible to update multiple rows with one query? Like in insert i can pass an array of objects and each key refers each column. Is there anything like that for an update query?

I have an array of objects (id, value) and i want to update all the fields that match id from the object with the value from the same object.

Comment: This can help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/40543668/4050261

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to update it using PostgreSQL query and it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799497/1162326). But it requires some magic and ugly `.raw` code to use this with `knex`. So, I'd recommend using multiple update statements in one [transaction](https://knexjs.org/#Transactions). And synchronize them using `Promise.all([updates])`.

Comment: if you use a `Promise.all` with a bunch of sql queries (all belonging to the same transaction), is knex smart enough/is thre the option to combine all the sql statements together and send it to the db in one go?

Comment: otherwise if you do an update of, say 10000 rows it feels like the multiple update statements in one transaction approach would have significantly worse performance

Comment: @friartuck yeah but you need to store all the update queries in an array (do not await first). You need to have an array of promises then you `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`