# SQLite: Insert 1 value per second or Multiple values per minute?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite in my mobile application to collect data from a sensor using Bluetooth Low Energy. Sensor is sending values every second. The approach I used is like this: When new data is received, I read it and insert it into a table in the database. The problem is: I noticed that the application crashes when it reaches 1500 insertion. My question is:

In term of performance, is it better to insert one value per second (the approach I am using today) or to collect 60 values in a array variable then insert them in one transaction ?

Is there any other way to optimize the performance of SQLite ? I need to keep the application running the whole day. That's 86400 values to be stored

Comment: 1 per sec VS 1 per min is not much difference in performance. It takes couple milliseconds to insert (if done right). `the application crashes when it reaches 1500 insertion` with which exception and on which lines of code? `Is there any other way to optimize the performance` we can't say as you didn't show your way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think he is using network at all, he is using SQLite

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I missed that `:-(` ... what I said might still hold, but not to the same degree, so I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this answer:

[Which is faster: multiple single INSERTs or one multiple-row INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793169/which-is-faster-multiple-single-inserts-or-one-multiple-row-insert)

The time required for inserting a row is determined by the following factors, where the numbers indicate approximate proportions:

> - Connecting: (3)
> - Sending query to server: (2)
> - Parsing query: (2)
> - Inserting row: (1 × size of row)
> - Inserting indexes: (1 × number of indexes)
> - Closing: (1)

In conlcusion, sending one query for 60 entries every minute is many times faster than sending a query every second.

Comment: when using SQLite, there is not network interaction, so steps 1...3 do not exist