# How can I import a SQL file into a Rails database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I've got a `.sql` file that I'd like to load into my Rails database using a Rake task. How can I do this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**The easiest way:**

```
bundle exec rails db < $SQL_FILE
```

*example:*

```
bundle exec rails db < my_db.sql
```

Comment: How could you add this to a Rake task?

Comment: with rails 5+ `rails db < my_sql.sql` would work as well

Comment: is it possible to set password as parameter for this task?

Comment: Yuri Karpovich, I don't know if it is possible to set password as parameter for this task, but it is possible to automatically provide the password from database.yml. `bundle exec rails db -p < my_db.sql`. You can find this and more options in `rails db --help`

Answer (score 48):

### The Easy Way

This works for simple cases.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("path/to/file"))
```

Solution found on the [Ruby On Rails mailing list](http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-April/030731.html) from 2006 (but still works in 2011 on Rails 3.1).

### Footnotes

- [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349636/how-to-import-a-big-sql-file-into-a-rails-database) implied this solution, but rejected it for big imports. I wanted to show it explicitly, since it works for smaller ones.
- The file I was trying to import contained a `LOCK TABLES` followed by an insert. The data was for a MySQL database. `Mysql2` said it had an invalid SQL syntax error until I removed the lock and unlock statements.

Comment: Update years later: instead of a Rake task, for PostgreSQL I just use `rake db:drop db:create` and then `cat somefile.sql | psql name_of_database`. Dumping is `pg_dump name_of_database > somefile.sql`.

Answer (score 17):

On MySQL this gave me a syntax error. Splitting the sql into statements made it work.

```
sql = File.read(sql_file)
statements = sql.split(/;$/)
statements.pop # remove empty line
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  statements.each do |statement|
    connection.execute(statement)
  end
end
```

Comment: I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: another command is already in progress`

Comment: My answer was for MySQL not Postgres. Seems like you have multiple processes accessing your db.

Comment: If you forget the ';' at the end of your SQL query, the `statements.pop # remote empty line` will remove your last query.  You can use the following to avoid that, `statements.pop if statements[-1] =~ /^\s+$/`

Comment: This is because Rails security prevents chaining queries. You can have multiple files, each with one query, and execute each file separately