# How do I most easily import from XLS into my rails app database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, import, xls

I started a project in Google Spreadsheets.  I am now learning Rails instead.  But I still have about 1000 records I'd like to import, to kick off my database.

[This railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) is great, but I don't need users to do it, and I only need to do it once.

I'd love a one-line solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342642/how-can-i-import-a-sql-file-into-a-rails-database) provides for SQL files... except that even if I had an SQL file (not an export option), I wouldn't know where to call that one line.

Thank you.

Comment: Download the Google spreadsheet as a CSV. Then try to find a CSV to database importer (I'm sure there are many).

Comment: Use a /lib/tasks/rake rake file with roo.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for a CSV-to-postgres importer...  though I'm less confident about finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgres-table)

In short you basically setup a CSV file that reflects the structure of the database table you're importing to

If you have to do some manipulation of the data you might find it easier to write something that reads your existing CSV format file and creates database records for each row.

Either using the csv gem or something like this:

https://github.com/pillowfactory/csv-mapper

Comment: Cool, there's a [CSV gem](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)!  That should be all I need to learn to use then, right?