# Postgresql - backup restore on different owner?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-restore

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31469008/4632019) I even vote up it, but unfortunately in my case I have `text` dump and I can not restore using `pg_restore` =(

```
zcat /home/kes/work/projects/bennet/db/bennet.sql.gz | \
    pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U bennet --no-owner --role=bennet  -d bennet
pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

But `psql` has no `role` and `no-owner` options

Is there a way to restore `text` dump on different owner?

Comment: If the original owner does not exist in the target db, you could use `psql -U new_owner -f yourscript.sql` and simply ignore the errors that ownership can't be restored

Answer (score 1):

No. You have two options:

- Manually edit the SQL script. This is cumbersom and error-prone.
- Restore the complete dump to a new, empty scratch database using `psql` and dump that with `--role` and `--no-owner` as you need.