# pg_restore not restoring sequences value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have 2 databases : `dbprod` and `dbdev`, with 2 users `uprod` and `udev`.

What I'd like to do is to copy the production database to my development database.

I succeeded to restore my database, but for some reason the value of my sequences are not set.

Here's what I'm doing :

```
// 1. Dumping
pg_dump --file '/home/punt/dump_db/prod.tar.gz' --format=t --schema 'public' 'dbprod'

// 2. Renaming the public schema to public_old
psql --dbname dbdev -c 'ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO public_old;'

// 3. Restoring
pg_restore --dbname='dbdev' --format=t --verbose /home/punt/dump_db/prod.tar.gz

// 4. And then I have to handle GRANTs...
```

Everything is working fine, except that the value of the sequences are not set.

I checked the content of my `prod.tar.gz` and I have the create and set, ex:

```
///...
CREATE SEQUENCE public.blockchain_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE public.blockchain_id_seq OWNER TO uprod;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.cryptocurrency_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.cryptocurrency_id_seq OWNER TO uprod;

//...

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.blockchain_id_seq', 34, true);
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.cryptocurrency_id_seq', 148, true);
```

And the --verbose does not show errors :

```
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.cryptocurrency_id_seq"
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.blockchain_id_seq"

// ...


pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET blockchain_id_seq
pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET cryptocurrency_id_seq
```

I'm thinking maybe some grants/privileges issue ?

Any idea ? Thanks.

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.17 (Debian 11.17-0+deb10u1)
```

Comment: No explanation. That should work.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I find the solution. I'm no expert Postgres, was "--clean --no-owner --no-privileges" the missing part ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So... I don't know what was wrong...

But here's the solution, based on this : [Postgresql - backup database and restore on different owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469008/postgresql-backup-database-and-restore-on-different-owner/67317144#67317144)

```
sudo -i -u postgres pg_dump --file /home/punt/dump_db/prod.tar.gz --format=t --clean --no-owner --no-privileges --schema public dbprod

sudo -i -u postgres psql --dbname dbdev -c 'ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO public_old;'

sudo -i -u postgres pg_restore --host localhost --username udev --password --dbname dbdev --no-owner --no-privileges --format t --verbose /home/punt/dump_db/prod.tar.gz
```

And then we can DROP public_old if we want. The solution with dropdb/createdb is also working, but I prefer to save the old schema and drop it when I need to.