# Artisan serve vs apache vhost

Tags: laravel-4

Using artisan serve fires up the laravel project

However when I set my vhosts to fire up this laravel project, it returns an error as below

```
PDOException was thrown when trying to write the session data: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'id' at row 1
```

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878779/sql-error-1406-data-too-long-for-column

Answer (score 0):

This is an SQL error. Check you  "String data" cause it doesnt fit the id column.