# Efficient multiple row inserts in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is faster: multiple single INSERTs or one multiple-row INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793169/which-is-faster-multiple-single-inserts-or-one-multiple-row-insert)

While going through a book on mysql, I found out two ways to insert a row in a database.

```
Method 1 

INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('a', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('d', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('e', 'b', 'c');

Method 2

INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'b', 'c'), ('e', 'b', 'c');
```

Is the second method more efficient than the first one ? Or does it simply calls the `Method 1` multiple times ?

Comment: [Read this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793169/which-is-faster-multiple-single-inserts-or-one-multiple-row-insert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is more efficient.

The first method creates a connection each time you want to insert a row, where the second uses a single connection to insert all your rows. There is, however, a `max_allowed_packet` that limits the length of the client's `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Can you give a brief idea abt the size of max_allowed_packet? Is it user configurable ?

Comment: @PrashantSingh [This](http://superuser.com/a/273833) topic explains what it controls and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5688506/679449) topic explains how to configure the setting.