# Is there a way to change wait_timeout and max_allowed_packet through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check and set max_allowed_packet mysql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688403/how-to-check-and-set-max-allowed-packet-mysql-variable)

I am having some database issues and I want to increase my `max_allowed_packet` timer and decrease `wait_timeout`. Is there a way to set it through PHP like `ini_set ( 'memory_limit', '32M' );` or something similar ?

Comment: Those are Mysql settings that can be set with a Mysql query either per connection (called *Session*) or for the server (called *Global*). You do know about the `SET` statement in Mysql? - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html - Whether or not you can change them depends on your database configuration and the access-level the user you connect to the database with has. It can not be generally answered if it is possible for you personally. Generally,  there is a way to configure that per connection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688403/how-to-check-and-set-max-allowed-packet-mysql-variable

Comment: THanks hakre i will check the link you supplied

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can issue the SQL

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=...
```

to change the value of `max_allowed_packet`, but as it is a [global variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) be aware that you have to reconnect for the change to become effective because changing global system variables does not affect currently open connections.

`wait_timeout` is a normal [session variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) that you can easily change for the current connection using

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout=...
```