# Maximum query length to avoid EPIPE error in node.js

Tags: node.js, bulkinsert, node-mysql, load-data-infile

I am using [felixge/node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module to interact with MySQL database from node.js. I have met the problem when inserting large amounts of data to database in one `INSERT` request.

Although [here](http://neatline.org/2012/11/28/populating-mysql-tables-with-node-js/) there is description of how to add 500,000 records to database using large
INSERT-queries, my script fails with the following error with much more small amounts of data:

```
{ [Error: write EPIPE] code: 'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall:
'write', fatal: true }
```

I think that this bug is somehow linked with the issue **#359** in mysql-node's github [Load data infile fails with EPIPE for large files](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/359), which is not assigned to someone yet for the last 5 months since creation.

So the what is practical size of queries which are guaranteed to be delivered?

Comment: This does not look like a bug, you can't assume connection to be 100% reliable. Remember last insertId, reconnect and continue.

Comment: @AndreySidorov But I have divided data into smaller packages and error disappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue just now and it turned out that the Mysql server I was talking to (it was on Amazon RDS) had its `max_allowed_packet` option set very low. Increasing that solved the issue for me.

I got the clue I needed by running the (very long) query from `mysql` on the commandline, and searching for the error message I got. I then got instructions for increasing the option on Amazon RDS from here: http://dev.n0ise.net/2012/10/amazon-rds-error-2006-hy000-at-line-xxx-mysql-server-has-gone-away/

See also this SO answer to see what that option is set to on your specific database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688506/496046

Comment: As I remember my issue was also on Amazon RDS

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem as well.

I've tried this library: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2

It's a drop in replacement for felixge's mysql driver, and I have not seen the EPIPE errors using it.