# the variable max_allowed_packet not able to be edited on MysQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, configuration

I tried to change its value but in vain, in fact I didn't find **my.ini** but i found many files of configuration and i edited them all(I edited the value of `max_allowed_packet` under `[mysqld]` section.
[image]
But I didn't get the result; the variable has not been changed

Comment: Maybe my.ini is located in bin folder

Comment: I did not find it in /bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate, please see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688403/how-to-check-and-set-max-allowed-packet-mysql-variable) can help to resolve your problem.

Also, Ivan is correct - the **my.ini** file should be in **bin**.

If the **my.ini** file cannot be found, any of the config files can be renamed to **my.cnf** to change MySQL's `max_allowed_packet` to the value of the `max_allowed_packet` variable in that config file.

Comment: I checked that answer before putting my question but it does not handle my problem

Comment: Have you searched the C drive for my.ini?

Comment: Yes  I did, but I think that all the 5 files above are config files

Comment: Yes. Those config files should have different values for the `max_allowed_packet`. If one of them suits your needs, try changing the name of it to **my.cnf**, then restart MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can locate the my.ini file from service properties, just run services.msc and open MySQL service.

[image]

If you mysql installation run as process then my.ini will be found in c:\windows

Comment: MySQL in my PC is not running as service, it is a process

Comment: Then maybe my.ini is in c:\windows