# PID error while sending mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Events ('.$names.') VALUES ('.$values.')';
//$names - string of all row names, $value - very long string with values
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die ($sql);
```

And mostly it does work, however sometimes I get similar error

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=10828 in /insert.php on line 107
>   INSERT INTO Events (work_hours, …) VALUES ('2015-06-28 11:00 (sekmadienis)', …)

Line 107 where mysqli_query is.
These … stand for my strings.

When I write all that $sql value directly to phpMyAdmin everything is OK — such query is inserted.

So my question is how to avoid that `PID` error and who causes it?

Comment: Have you tried increasing mysql max allowed packet size ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the max_allowed_packet setting for MySQL. You need to increase the value.

You can set and check it's value by following this 
[how to check and set max_allowed_packet mysql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688403/how-to-check-and-set-max-allowed-packet-mysql-variable)

Comment: My hosting does not provide such option. And the value of it is 8388608 (perhaps bits).