# Unable to connect online mysql database to java application

Tags: java, mysql, database

> Error
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (5526600 > >1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the >max_allowed_packet' variable.

but my hosted online mysql server has this value which is too much big than 1048576

> max allowed packet = 268,435,456

Comment: Check if the value `268,435,456` is under Global settings / Session settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting again the max value

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=500M
```

Comment: Yes, i have been trying but i have faced this error 
#1227 - access denied you need the super privilege for this operation

Comment: on unix try "sudo ... " windows maybe open with admin privileges

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, it turns out this error message can be misleading as **the client has the same setting as well** and has to have the correct value.

Try [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42369706/4539156).