# Save array in mysql database using PHP (json_encode)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have large size array which I want to save directly in mysql database . Before saving, I encode the array using **json_encode** , but whenever I try to save the data, Error arise.

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes.
```

I increase the max_allowed_packet value in /etc/my.cnf and restart MySQL service also but that doesnt work out !!

Comment: It may help :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688403/how-to-check-and-set-max-allowed-packet-mysql-variable

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size

Comment: Just how big is this data? And what does the PHP/SQL code look like that is trying to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `xamp/mysql/bin/my.cnf` try changing the `max_allowed _packet` and `net_buffer_length` to

```
max_allowed_packet='required size'
net_buffer_length='required size'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON size is a problem, you could try making the column a blob, and then compressing (and by a SELECT decompressing) the JSON string with bzip:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bzcompress.php

This does make the field unsearchable for the SELECT command, so it's not gonna work if you need to search the string via SQL.