# MySQL Insert query fails with too much data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a very large amount of data into a MySQL database using this basic code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO PublicNoticesTable (url, county, paperco, date, notice, id) VALUES " . $queryString;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

The `$queryString` is generated beforehand and contains thousands of lines of information in the format of:

`('a', 'b', 'c'),('a', 'b', 'c');`

That way I can insert multiple rows of data in one mysql call and to reduce the processing time.  I have the ability to throttle the amount of information that goes into `$queryString` and when I have a smaller amount of information the query succeeds. YAY!  When I put a little bit too much information the query fails.  If anyone could provide a solution for me it would be greatly appreciated.  I am using GoDaddy and PHPMyAdmin, if that's important.

Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get when the query fails?

Comment: please show the query that is failing with the error message to debug

Comment: There is no error message?  If there is I am not sure how to retrieve it.  All I know is that `$result` returns false

Comment: atleast write the query which is failing because we cannot understand what you mean by little too much information .. I mean just a sample query with hard coded values

Comment: if it returns false, then you need to use `mysqli_error($connect)` on the query, see if that yields anything.

Comment: I inserted `mysqli_error($connect)` into the fail statement and I get a white screen of death, the actual query doesn't run anymore even with small amounts of data.  I can't share the actual data contained in the query as it is sensitive information.  I can say that it is properly formatted because obviously the query works with small amounts, and doesn't with large amounts.

Comment: Add mysqli error reporting. It's widely documented

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to  insert the values using `INSERT ... VALUES` pattern then you have the limit of `max_allowed_packet`.When I put a little bit too much information the query fails then why not now debug `mysqli_error($connect)`

**From Docs :**

> To optimize insert speed, combine many small operations into a single
>   large operation. Ideally, you make a single connection, send the data
>   for many new rows at once, and delay all index updates and consistency
>   checking until the very end.

MySQL client or the mysqld server receives a packet bigger than `max_allowed_packet` bytes, it issues a Packet too large error and closes the connection.

Try to view what is the max size of packet

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
```

> The SQL length is limited by 1M default, you can change
>   `max_allowed_packet` parameter to support more bigger single insert.

Comment: How would I go about locating this 'max_allowed_packet' value?

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size?answertab=active#tab-top and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688403/how-to-check-and-set-max-allowed-packet-mysql-variable?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that the maximum length for your columns is enough to incorporate your data. If your data is really long (more than about 10,000 characters in each column), you could try using a blob.