# unable to start mysql server. Error preceding group in config

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, homebrew

so i've been trying for a good 2-3 hours now to fix several issues when it came to installing mysql.
Now, i'm currently stuck on this one:

when typing: `mysql.server restart`

this prints out in the terminal:

```
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook.local.pid).
```

my `my.cnf` file contains the following: (and is located in `~/etc`)

```
[mysqld_safe]
 [mysqld]
 [client]
port        = 3306
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer          = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size   = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size    = 16M
log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
query-cache-type = 1
default-storage-engine=innodb 
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
 
[mysql]
[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try not indenting the `[mysqld]` and `[client]` lines.

Comment: still the same error @Barmar

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020297/mysql-my-cnf-file-found-option-without-preceding-group

Comment: Google for the error message, you'll find a number of threads in many different forums. Probably your problem is the same as one of them.

Comment: already tried, hence why i turned here for advice @Barmar

Comment: The error message says the location of the file is `/etc`, not `~/etc`. Are you sure you're looking at the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting the code that was in `my.cfn` and using sublime text 2 to save it did the trick...

Comment: You probably had some invisible characters in the file, as indicated in the question I linked to in the comment.