# How to Import data (.sql fle) in mysql whose size is greater than 200 MB

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a backup of database whose size is 200 MB, and i want to import it in my database. I tried and i got the error message saying the size is greater. I tried with php.ini and increased the size of upload file as :-

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
  upload_max_filesize = 300M
```

and when i restarted my wamp server it still allows to upload 8 MBs only. How can i restore the database in mysql whose size is much greater then 2 or 8 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Restore or an Execute Large Script tools in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/); these tools will help you to execute SQL script against the database.

1. Create **SSH** connection.
2. Open Restore or Execute Large Script wizard in the Database menu, select the SQL file, connection, target database
3. Click 'Execute'.

Try trial version. Command line is supported.

Answer (score 6):

Make these changes into the php.ini file.

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M 
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
max_execution_time = 30 
max_input_time = 60 
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000 
max_input_time = 5000 
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Then restart wamp/lampp/xampp for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing with PHP or just plain MySQL?

This might help:
[MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes)

If that doesn't work out you could try to use an SQL dump file splitter like:
http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/

Comment: i am importing via phpmyadmin

Comment: [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/import-mysql-dumpfile-sql-datafile-into-my-database/) is a guide for importing SQL files using SSH.

Answer (score 1):

open: 
    /wamp/bin/apache/apachex.x.x/bin/php.ini 
AS WELL AS 
    /wamp/bin/php/phpx.x.x/php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 250M (this can vary according to the required size) 
post_max_size = 300M  (this needs to be bigger than previous line)
memory_limit = 350M  (this needs to be bigger than both the previous lines)
```

restart wamp

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `post_max_size` in your php.ini like this:

```
post_max_size = 300M
```

Tell me the result please.

Comment: i got the following error message
No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.

Answer (score 0):

If there are still problems, try and edit the phpmyadmin.conf file in the alias folder (x:\wamp\alias). 
For example :

  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 250M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 250M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 3600
  php_admin_value max_input_time 3600

Together with tweaking the php.ini files this worked for me