# Error while importing .sql through command line

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line, ubuntu-11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than ‘max_allowed_packet’ bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes)

I have the .sql file which size is 26.3 MB and containing large data.

I am trying to import it via command line by using this command :

```
mysql -uroot -p dbname < /path/to/file.sql
```

But it's showing following error while importing

```
ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 1: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

Is it the problem of size or if not then what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: try editing the mysql config file (mysqld.ini i think) and raise the value of max_allowed_paket. The size of the .sql shouldn't be the problem because it's not all loaded at once, but the way it's created.

Comment: see [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in mysql prompt, issue these commands:

```
        set global net_buffer_length=100000000; 
        set global max_allowed_packet=10000000000;
```

run your  command
      `mysql -uroot -p dbname < /path/to/file.sql`

in another  terminal

Comment: Ok..I went through it but still it showing error

Comment: please see the duplicate question and make changes in the `my.conf` file

Comment: I made changes in my.cnf `max_allowed_packet = 100M` now still problem persist and now it also showing warning : `Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored

ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 1: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`

Comment: "is ignored" means you effectively have not changed any relevant settings - fix your permissions instead of introducing new problems

Comment: have u tried all the solution, specified  in the link

Comment: use the following command to change file’s permissions "
 chmod 644 /etc/mysql/my.cnf "

Comment: don't forget restart mysql service after making the changes in conf