# error mysql : Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

for import mysql database give me this error :

```
$ `mysql -u user -p password zxc_db < zxc.sql`
ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 96: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

Please give me a best solution to solve it ?
tanx .

Comment: Do you mean other than `"increase max_allowed_packet in my.cnf"`?

Comment: Another thread answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes Basically, you need to change the settings both on the dameon and on the client.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the best solution is " change mysql.cnf "
debian :
 /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
change this line ==> `max_allowed_packet      = 16M`
to : `max_allowed_packet      = 128M`

or 
add --max_allowed_packet=128M to your mysqldump command.

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=128M -u user -ppass database < database.sql
```

Comment: tried that, yet received same error message as before...

Comment: Still receiving this error message after doing this.

Comment: From the link shared by @PrimozRome, before running your import, run this:
mysql -uroot -p -e "set global net_buffer_length=1000000; set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;"

Comment: When you change the mysql.cnf file, you need to restart the server before that setting is refreshed.