# Import DB with `max_allowed_packet` limitation issue and no admin access

Tags: mysql, shell

While importing a full database on a remote server :  `mysql -h foo < dump_file.sql`, it returns  *ERROR 1153 ... Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes*. But I don't have admin rights on that server to change my.cnf settings. The limit is 16Mb

I tried to optimize the dump like following, without result :

```
mysqldump --skip-extended-insert --net_buffer_length=10000 DATABASE_NAME > dump_file.sql
```

Would it be helpful to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` Is there any possible syntax to use it without specifying `INTO TABLE` ... ?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE dump_file.sql
```

Or any other way to turn around that issue  ?

**EDIT :** previous question asks :

> Where do I change max_allowed_packet to be able to import the dump? Is
>   there anything else I should set?

when I merely know where to change `max_allowed_packet`, but I have not enough rights to do it.

So I specifically asked **how to do it with CLI only**, and if it would be **helpful or not to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`** in my case, which is not at all in the other question. Whatever, duplicated or not, I got an answer who solved the issue.

Comment: @l0b0 Kind of dupe yes, but I had read this answer already and it gives an admin solution, this is why I specified *no admin access* in the title. Indeed, it looks like I can't do this without changing the server configuration, but I asked because I want/need to be sure :)

Comment: Well, if they say ["you have to change it for both the client and the daemon mysqld server"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722656/96588) that's pretty clear...

Comment: Yes @l0b0, thank you. But @Giles option `--max_allowed_packet=16M` added to the other set of options `--skip-extended-insert --net_buffer_length=10000` did the job. I managed to solve that issue without changing the server configuration ;-) Very happy end for my current dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqldump also allows a parameter for this - try adding --max_allowed_packet=16M to your dump command.