# how can fix error 1064 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, import

```
Error

SQL query:

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (2388, 60, '_count-views_day-20130726', '2'), 
(2389, 140, '_count-views_day-20130726', '61'), 
(2391, 82, '_count-views_day-20130726', '2'), 
(2392, 22, '_count-views_day-20130726', '23'), 
(2393, 78, '_count-views_day-20130726', '7'), 
(2394, 35, '_count-views_day-20130726', '2'), 
(2395, 32, '_count-views_day-20130726', '2'), 
(2396, 13, '_count-views_day-20130726', '1'), 
(2397, 83, '_count-views_day-20130726', '9'), 
(2398, 137, '_count-views_day-20130726', '8'), 
(2399, 90, '_count-views_day-20130726', '6'), 
(2400, 68, '_count-views_day-20130726', '1'), 
(2401, 6, '_count-views_day-20130726', '1'), 
(2402, 79, '_count-views_day-20130726', '5'), 
(2403, 33, '_count-views_day-20130726', '2'), 
(2404, 33, '_count-views_week-201330', '6'), 
(2405, 61, '_count-views_day-20130726', '8'), 
(2406, 141, '_count-views_day-20130726', '5'), 
(2408, 49, '_count-views_day-20130726', '8'), 
(2409, 22, '_count-views_day-20130727', [...]

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''_count' at line 1045
```

How can I fix that error?
I was going import by MySQL!

Comment: Where'd you get this insert statement from?

Comment: @developerwjk, it's a mysqldump file for a Wordpress database.

Comment: How are you using the query? Pasting it into the console? or running a .sql file? (Hint: you should run the .sql script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It seems that your INSERT statement is too long.</strike>

Try increasing max_allowed_packet at my.cnf. For instance, max_allowed_packet=512MB

Try following commmand :

```
mysql your_wordpress_db < your_dumped_file.sql
```

Comment: can you write more details?

Comment: Wouldn't that throw a [different error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes)?

Comment: This is wrong. Probably he's pasting it in the console rather than running the .sql file which is the right way to do it.

Comment: @showdev thanks. maybe 1153 ?

Comment: @SaebKhanzadeh ok. but first, let me know. How did you run that sql statement? via phpadmin? via command line?

Comment: by phpadmin @turutosiya

Comment: @SaebKhanzadeh then, you upload .sql file? Or paste the sql statement?

Comment: i upload @turutosiya

Comment: @SaebKhanzadeh thanks. Can you confirm that your .sql file is not trimmed?  I mean that I doubt that your .sql file doesn't contain full dump of the db.

Comment: @turutosiya wow, but i have only that!!! if your thought be correct how can i fix it?

Comment: @SaebKhanzadeh In case your .sql doesn't contain complete statement, we have no option to fix the issue. You can open .sql with text editor. Please check.