# Can't Export DB With Mysql Dump Error 2020:

Tags: php, mysql

Having trouble creating a database backup on shared hosting where I do not have control over mysql config.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
mysqldump: Error 2020: Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes when dumping table `wp_postmeta` at row: 870
```

Is there a workaround or a script I can use to dump the DB in a more optimal state?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max\_allowed\_packet' bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase 'max_allowed_packet' value like this

```
shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=512M
```

For detail info see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).