# Inserting big data, more than "max_allowed_packet" can I dodge it somehow?

Tags: mysql

Im inserting blob data to MySQL table, but now the size exceed "max_allowed_packet" settings. Its the limit of server, I cant increase that. Can I somehow insert bigger data more than that? I already gz_compress-ed the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definitely can't change the `max_allowed_packet size` (though I recommend you try - see [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93128/505722) ). Then you may be able to upload the data in parts. I haven't tried this so you'll likely want to test:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, dat) VALUES (1, startOfBlob);
UPDATE foo SET dat = CONCAT(dat,secondBitOfBlob) WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE foo SET dat = CONCAT(dat,thirdBitOfBlob) WHERE id = 1;
```

This can fragment the blob so you'll likely want to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` after this.

If the blobs you are storing are very large you also may want to consider storing them differently - i.e. split over rows or stored in a file somewhere.

Comment: neat. Nice. Tricky.
THIS SHOULD BE TEACHED!

Comment: .... sadly not. It turned out it still wont work, because of the max_allowed_packet setting