# MySQL Migration Wizard results in 'Found record bigger than max_allowed_packet'

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-migration

I am trying to migrate a database from MSSQL 2014 to MySQL 5.7 using Workbench 6.3 (CE) on a Windows machine. I have already set the value of max_allowed_packet to 1G in my.ini file. However, I'm still getting the error while trying to migrate the data. The table for which I am getting this error has only one record, and even the field, which I suspect is causing the issue, doesn't have that big of a value
`<results><result documentId="1" queryCode="AZ100" queryValue="I"/></results>`.
The field has nvarchar(max) as its data type in MSSQL which gets converted to LONGTEXT by MySQL wizard.

**EDIT:** I am not using any client here, just using the Workbench for migration. Also, in the migration log it indicates that it has detected the new max_allowed_packet value `copytable]: Detected max_allowed_packet=1073741824`

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max\_allowed\_packet' bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93128/3900824)

Please check the answer in the link and see if it solves your issue.

> You probably have to change it for both the client (you are running to do the import) AND the daemon mysqld that is running and accepting the import.

Comment: nvarchar(max) can take up to 2 GB. Maybe that's the issue?