# Is there any way to set 'max_allowed_packet' in mysql npm?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using below code for mysql connection and trying to upload a blob data in column.

```
require('dotenv').config()
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  supportBigNumbers: true
});
```

I am on localhost and has one database, with two projects setup, if I use project1 then no error is coming but if I use project2 then it is giving the error "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes".

I am unable to bebug what is the problem with my project2 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

According to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/104176/9668272

`max_allowed_packet` is set on SQL server side.

So, its more likely that somewhere in your project2 you send really big query to SQL server.

There are basically two ways to resolve it:

- you can increase `max_allowed_packet` on your SQL server
- or you can add project2 code to your question