# ERROR 2020 (HY000): Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes, when trying to retrieve data from a table

Tags: mysql, innodb, max-allowed-packet

I am working on my local set up of a web application and I have to fetch all the items in a table, but when I do `select * from my_table`, it gives me this error`ERROR 2020 (HY000): Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`.

I have tried many options, some of which include:

-Setting `max_allowed_packet` in my `\etc\mysql\mysql.conf.d\mysqld.cnf`  and `\etc\mysql\mysql.conf.d\mysqldump.cnf`(I am not using dump, but to be on safe side), to 1G then 2G etc.

-Also tried using `set global net_buffer_length=1000000;` and `set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;` in mysql in terminal

I got a bit of success when I used `mysql --max_allowed_packet=100M -u root -` it gives all the data but the problem is it works only in the terminal, but I have to get data in my web application where it will not work.

***The interesting thing is:*** I tried using limit, so when I use `select * from my_table limit 200`, it gives expected result(but 200 rows only). Total rows are approx 350, So the error is in data of higher rows than 200. To checkout size of row result I used following query:
`select sum(row_size) from ( select char_length(id)+ char_length(code)+ char_length(name)+ char_length(url) +char_length(group)+  char_length(template)+  char_length(html) + char_length(association) + char_length(status) + char_length(created_at)+ char_length(updated_at) + char_length(html_generation_date) as row_size from myTable limit 311,1) as tbl1;` Which gives me: 43095
while for `limit 150,1` above query gives: 94428. So row size doesn't seem to be a problem.

I tried solutions given on [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes) and https://serverfault.com/questions/102564/error-2020-got-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes-when-dumping-table.

Basically, I want to do something like this: `myTable::model()->findAll();` in my PHP Yii app which is equivalent to `select * from my_table` and afterwards I can use the data to populate my list.

Table Schema is:
`+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| code          | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| name          | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| url           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| group         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| template      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| html          | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| association          | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| status               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at           | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated_at           | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| html_generation_date | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |`

And the mysql version is: 14.14 Distribution: 5.7.26. DB engine is InnoDB.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: *"i got a bit of success when I used mysql --max_allowed_packet=100M -u root - it gives all the data but the problem is it works only in the terminal, but I have to get data in my web application where it will not work."* This web application code is missing and it ideally should be posted as well.

Comment: But most likely you need to use `SET SESSION max_allowed_packet  = 1000000000;` as separated query in the application code.. As `SET GLOBAL` always require `SUPER` privilege

Comment: Lets put the web application aside, I want to configure MySQL server and client on localhost to handle large enough packet size say up to 1G without passing it in MySQL client command parameter.

Comment: SET GLOBAL applies only to _subsequent_ logins.

Comment: SET GLOBAL also doesn't work out, still getting the error. I think I will have to change the config files, which somehow are not working for now.

Comment: I have tried changing max_packet_size already, the effect shows in SHOW VARIABLES. But still, no effect; seems the value is being ignored.