# Using npm mysql module, query source and path problem in windows

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using npm mysql module on windows 7.

```
connection.query(`source D:/mediapropel/wp_default_install.sql`, function (error, results, fields) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log("Database should be created1");
    console.log('source '+ path.join(__dirname, '..', "\/\wp_default_install.sql")+'');
    res.send('');
});
```

What I have tried:

1. `'source D:/mediapropel/wp_default_install.sql'`
2. `'source '+ path.join(__dirname, '..', "\/\wp_default_install.sql")+''`
3. `"source " + "D:/mediapropel/wp_default_install.sql"`
4. `"source D:/\mediapropel/\wp_default_install.sql"`
5. `"source D:/\mediapropel/\wp_default_install.sql/\/"`

Error message:

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'source D:/mediapropel/wp_default_install.sql\' at line 1'`

The same query runs directly in the mysql command line properly as expected. Please advice where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the `mysql` module, as explained [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2103). Also, you can test this if you try the same `SOURCE` SQL command in DB admin UIs like phpMyAdmin.
I've tried using `child_process.exec` on the `/bin/mysql` executable, but failed for some reason.
A hacky solution(that worked for me) could be the one below, where you read and send the whole script for execution(notice the `multipleStatements: true` setting, when creating the connection):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '[host]',
  database: '[database]',
  user: '[user]',
  password: '[password]',
  multipleStatements: true
});
const connectionQueryPromise = promisify(connection.query.bind(connection));

const dbImportScript = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dump.sql'));
await connectionQueryPromise(dbImportScript);
```

If you get an error about `max_allowed_packet`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes) answer.